# Can PostgreSQL index array columns?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, indexing, operators

I can't find a definite answer to this question in the documentation. If a column is an array type, will all the entered values be individually indexed?

I created a simple table with one `int[]` column, and put a unique index on it. I noticed that I couldn't add the same array of ints, which leads me to believe the index is a composite of the array items, not an index of each item.

```
INSERT INTO "Test"."Test" VALUES ('{10, 15, 20}');
INSERT INTO "Test"."Test" VALUES ('{10, 20, 30}');

SELECT * FROM "Test"."Test" WHERE 20 = ANY ("Column1");
```

Is the index helping this query?

Comment: Is it possible to use the datatype `jsonb` and use the indexes? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html and https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING

Answer (score 271, accepted):

Yes you can index an array, but you have to use the [array operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html) and the [GIN-index type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-types.html).

Example:

```
    CREATE TABLE "Test"("Column1" int[]);
    INSERT INTO "Test" VALUES ('{10, 15, 20}');
    INSERT INTO "Test" VALUES ('{10, 20, 30}');
    
    CREATE INDEX idx_test on "Test" USING GIN ("Column1" gin__int_ops);
            
    EXPLAIN ANALYZE
    SELECT * FROM "Test" WHERE "Column1" @> ARRAY[20];
```

Result:

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on "Test"  (cost=4.26..8.27 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.014..0.015 rows=2 loops=1)
  Recheck Cond: ("Column1" @> '{20}'::integer[])
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_test  (cost=0.00..4.26 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=2 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ("Column1" @> '{20}'::integer[])
Total runtime: 0.062 ms
```

##### Note

it appears that in many cases the **gin__int_ops** option is required

```
create index <index_name> on <table_name> using GIN (<column> gin__int_ops)
```

I have not yet seen a case where it would work with the && and @> operator without the gin__int_ops options

Comment: As the OP surmises, this doesn't actually index individual array values, but instead indexes the entire array. So, while this will help the query in question (see explain plan), this means you can't create unique constraints (easily) on individual array values. That said, if you are using integer arrays, you can use the contrib module "intarray" to index individual array values, which can be much faster in many cases. (IIRC there is some work being done on this for text values, but contributors would probably be welcome to help finish it off).

Comment: Please don't use uppercase letters in PostgreSQL identifiers in code examples, it just confuses people who aren't familiar with the quoting/case folding rules, particularly people new to PostgreSQL.

Comment: To repeat my comment here: from my experience, these indexes offer little to no speedup *unless* `gin__int_ops` is used for `integer[]` columns. It took me years of frustration and looking for other solutions until I discovered this op class. It's a borderline miracle worker.

Comment: @IamIC does that mean I should not bother indexing an array of strings? And I should only index integer arrays?

Comment: Operator class "gin__int_ops" is only required if you have installed "intarray" extension, otherwise the index works by default. I have expanded on this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63996454/postgres-doesnt-use-index-on-integer-array/63996455#63996455

Comment: @xzilla Are you sure? The [definition](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/gin-intro.html) of "generalized inverted index" is exactly the fact that it can index the composite values (unlike btree which indexes the entire value)

Answer (score 147):

@Tregoreg raised a ***question*** in the comment to his offered bounty:

> I didn't find the current answers working. Using GIN index on
> array-typed column does not increase the performance of ANY()
> operator. Is there really no solution?

[@Frank's accepted ***answer***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4059785/939860) tells you to use **array operators**, which is *still correct* for Postgres 11. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-types.html)

> ... the standard distribution of PostgreSQL includes a GIN operator
> class for arrays, which supports indexed queries using these
> operators:
>
> ```
> <@
> @>
> =
> &&
> ```

[The complete list of built-in operator classes for GIN indexes in the standard distribution is here.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/gin-builtin-opclasses.html#GIN-BUILTIN-OPCLASSES-TABLE)

In Postgres **indexes are bound to operators** (which are implemented for certain types), not data types alone or functions or anything else. That's a [heritage from the original Berkeley design of Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/history.html) and very hard to change now. And it's generally working just fine. [Here is a thread on pgsql-bugs with Tom Lane commenting on this.](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/20150123181759.32669.55573@wrigleys.postgresql.org#16692.1422111691@sss.pgh.pa.us)

<sub>Some PostGis *functions* (like [`ST_DWithin()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html)) seem to violate this principal, but that is not so. Those functions are rewritten internally to use respective *operators*.</sub>

The indexed expression must be to the *left* of the operator. For most operators (*including all of the above*) the query planner can achieve this by flipping operands if you place the indexed expression to the right - given that a [`COMMUTATOR`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xoper-optimization.html#XOPER-COMMUTATOR) has been defined. The [`ANY` construct](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.28.17) can be used in combination with various operators and is not an operator itself. When used as `constant = ANY (array_expression)` only indexes supporting the `=` operator on *array elements* would qualify and we would need a commutator for `= ANY()`. GIN indexes are out.

Postgres is not currently smart enough to derive a GIN-indexable expression from it. For starters, `constant = ANY (array_expression)` is **not completely equivalent** to `array_expression @> ARRAY[constant]`. Array operators return an error if any NULL *elements* are involved, while the `ANY` construct can deal with NULL on either side. And there are different results for data type mismatches.

Related answers:

- [Check if value exists in Postgres array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231544/check-if-value-exists-in-postgres-array/11231965#11231965)
- [Index for finding an element in a JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404055/index-for-finding-an-element-in-a-json-array/18405706#18405706)
- [SQLAlchemy: how to filter on PgArray column types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10344468/sqlalchemy-how-to-filter-on-pgarray-column-types/10344851#10344851)
- [Can IS DISTINCT FROM be combined with ANY or ALL somehow?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/60378/3684)

#### Asides

While working with **`integer` arrays** (`int4`, not `int2` or `int8`) without `NULL` values (like your example implies) consider the additional module [**`intarray`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/intarray.html), that provides specialized, faster operators and index support. See:

- [How to create an index for elements of an array in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867577/how-to-create-an-index-for-elements-of-an-array-in-postgresql/10868144#10868144)
- [Compare arrays for equality, ignoring order of elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870105/compare-arrays-for-equality-ignoring-order-of-elements/12870508#12870508)

As for the `UNIQUE` constraint in your question that went unanswered: That's implemented with a btree index on the *whole array* value (like you suspected) and does not help with the search for *elements* at all. Details:

- [How does PostgreSQL enforce the UNIQUE constraint / what type of index does it use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9066972/how-does-postgresql-enforce-the-unique-constraint-what-type-of-index-does-it-u/9067108#9067108)

Comment: Aaaaaaah, feeling quite embarrassed right now, but it just didn't come to my mind that postgres would not use the index even if theoretically possible. Maybe it's also because my lack of insight into postgres, such as that indices are bound to operators. Thank you for taking time to answer my ill-posed question and sharing your knowledge!

Comment: @Tregoreg: Don't be too embarrassed, it's really not too obvious. I remember being confused by this myself when I first ran into it. The added question and clarification should be quite useful to the general public.

Comment: From my experience, these indexes offer little to no speedup *unless* `gin__int_ops` is used for `integer[]` columns. It took me years of frustration and looking for other solutions until I discovered this op class. It's a borderline miracle worker.

Comment: @IamIC: I added pointers to intarray. Seems noteworthy, as you pointed out.

Comment: For `ANY (array_expression) = constant` expressions, GIN indexes work fine?

Answer (score 36):

It's now possible to index the individual array elements. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE test (foo int[]);
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('{1,2,3}');
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('{4,5,6}');
CREATE INDEX test_index on test ((foo[1]));
SET enable_seqscan TO off;

EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * from test WHERE foo[1]=1;
                                                QUERY PLAN                                                    
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using test_index on test  (cost=0.00..8.27 rows=1 width=32) (actual   time=0.070..0.071 rows=1 loops=1)
   Index Cond: (foo[1] = 1)
 Total runtime: 0.112 ms
(3 rows)
```

This works on at least Postgres 9.2.1. Note that you need to build a separate index for each array index, in my example I only indexed the first element.

Comment: Let it not be lost - this approach is hopeless for variable length array where you want to use the ANY() operator.

Comment: This is really not very useful. If you have a fixed number of array elements, you'd rather use individual columns for each element (and plain btree indices) instead of building a more expensive expression index for each array item. Storage of individual columns is much cheaper without array overhead, too.