# How to add a foreign key constraint on the elements of array data type

Tags: java, sql, foreign-keys, hsqldb

I am trying to execute this hsql query but I am getting execetion because 'SYMPTOMS' in PATIENTVISIT is of type Array Varchar() where as 'SYMPTOM_NAME' in table SYMPTOMS is of type varchr() :

```
 ALTER TABLE PATIENTVISIT ADD CONSTRAINT IF NOT EXISTS 
 PATIENTVISIT_SYMPTOMS_FK FOREIGN KEY (SYMPTOMS) REFERENCES SYMPTOMS(SYMPTOM_NAME);
```

The exception I am getting is:

```
 java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: incompatible data types in combination in statement [ALTER TABLE PATIENTVISIT ADD CONSTRAINT IF NOT EXISTS PATIENTVISIT_SYMPTOMS_FK FOREIGN KEY (SYMPTOMS) REFERENCES SYMPTOMS(SYMPTOM_NAME)]
```

How to resolve this issue or what is the workaround?

Comment: A FK says a  subrow value for some columns appears elsewhere. So the column types must be the same. They aren't, so you can't execute that. Explain what you want to accomplish. Please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/15513728/3404097

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want only the values in the SYSMPTOM_NAME column to be used as elements of the array in PATIENTVISIT. Only the recognized SYMPTOM_NAME values are allowed as valid symptoms.

This type of constraint cannot be defined using a FOREIGN KEY.

You can use a TRIGGER on the PATIENTVISIT table that checks all the elements of the array against those in the SYMPTOMS table and throws an exception if there is an unrecognised value.

```
CREATE TRIGGER CHECK_VALUES BEFORE INSERT ON PATIENTVISIT REFERENCING NEW  ROW AS NEWROW FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN ATOMIC
 IF EXISTS (SELECT TRUE FROM UNNEST (NEWROW.SYMPTOMS) X(A) LEFT JOIN SYMPTOMS ON X.A = SYMPTOMS.SYMPTOM_NAME WHERE SYMPTOMS.SYMPTOM_NAME IS NULL)
  THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000';
  END IF;
END
```