# Unique index on multiple fields... but not the way you think

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, multiple-columns, unique-constraint

Is there a way to create a unique index on two integer fields, such that a given integer can only appear once in **one** of those fields? I.e.

```
+------+-------+
| Left | Right |
+------+-------+
|    1 |     2 |
|   *2*|     3 | < INVALID
+------+-------+
```

EDIT: note, the `left..right` range should still be able to contain other ranges in their entirety:

```
+------+-------+
| Left | Right |
+------+-------+
|    1 |     4 |
|    2 |     3 | < VALID CHILD
+------+-------+
```

I'm using Rails 4 and Postgres 9.2.

Comment: I think this could be achieved using the new range data type and an exclusion constraint.

Comment: an exclusion constraint would stop 4 and 5 being added if a record existed with Left=3 and Right=6

Comment: [This related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016776/can-postgresql-have-a-uniqueness-constraint-on-array-elements/8017013#8017013) provides a solution for a similar case (trigger + additional table + unique constraint). Look to the second chapter ("Solution for the dark side").

Answer (score 1):

Not with a simple b-tree unique index. You can require distinct *pairs* - and with a functional index, can ignore pair ordering - but the index gets one leaf per tuple and there really isn't a way around that.

As horse says, you'd need to turn your values into a range type and then use an exclusion constraint to enforce it. Or just use a trigger - slower, but easy.

**Edit**: Looks like your original question completely misstated the goal. You're not interested in individual values at all, you're treating the pairs as ranges. You appear to want to:

- Exclude ranges that partially overlap; but
- Permit ranges that wholly overlap (one contains the other) or do not overlap at all.

It is possible you might be able to achieve this with some work using [exclusion constraints](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION) - but I somewhat doubt it, since exclusion constraints aren't supposed to allow *any* overlap. Again, you're probably looking at a trigger-based solution here.

Comment: Is there a way to make it so ranges can be contained but can't overlap? I've edited the post to show this requirement.

Comment: @Patrick Ok, so your question was totally different to what you originally wrote. Updated.