# Check if any of a given array of values are present in a Postgres array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm writing a Rails 4 app and have a string array column on one of my models called `identifiers`. When the user passes in a list of identifiers, what's the syntax to fetch the rows where any of the given identifiers match any of the stored identifiers?

I'm trying `where('ARRAY[?] == any(identifiers)', ids)`, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Is this column being serialized in your model?

Comment: No serialization happens... Postgres natively supports arrays on columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [array operator "overlap": **`&&`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html)

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE ARRAY[1,2,3] && identifiers
```

Or:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE '{1,2,3}'::int[] && identifiers
```

You did not disclose the exact type, which must match, of course. My example is for integer arrays.

This form can utilize a GIN index on the identifiers column:

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_identifiers_gin_idx ON tbl USING GIN (identifiers);
```