# Search database with Array to Match individual value from another Array

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

Ok this is a bit complex

I currently have a search function that allows customers to search records based on 1 or more states.

they can enter multiple states and this function will search the post to match the post that matches any one of those states.

With this the post can only have 1 state.

I am tring to expand and allow each post to have multiple states. but for this to happen i need to figure out how to match any one of the seached states to any one of the posted states.

In this example `type = "dest"` and `states = "mo, ks, ar, ok"`

```
def PrepareSearch.states(type, states)
  states = states.split(",")
  st = ""
  states.each {|s| st += "'#{s}'," }
  st = st[0..-2]
  "#{type}_state IN (#{st})"
end
```

It would match a post that has any one of those states in dest_state and only has 1 of them in it

I need this to be expanded and match something like this:

```
dest_state = "mo, ks, ok, ar" 

states = "ks, ne, co"
```

I need that to match because `ks` is in both

But i also need it to work if it only has one state in the `dest_state` as well

**my database has 100k + records that this will be searching thru.**

**`dest_state` is a stored field in the record in the database**

Comment: Do you want to match "any" of the states or *all* of the states?

Comment: Any of the searched states to any of the Posted States...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Postgres "overlap" operator **`&&`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-OPERATORS-TABLE):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE dest_state && states;
```

An additional benefit is that this operator can be supported with a **GIN index** on the state array column. Makes a *huge* difference for performance. Example:

- [Check if any of a given array of values are present in a Postgres array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20288639/check-if-any-of-a-given-array-of-values-are-present-in-a-postgres-array/20289634#20289634)

Since your table is big I would use `int` or `smallint` instead of strings as "state" codes. Or use an [**`enum`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-enum.html).

Another option would be to [normalize your database schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and implement this as n:m relationship between posts and states. Details:

- [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql/9790225#9790225)

Comment: That's fine. `&&` is an SQL operator for arrays.

Comment: Was kind of hoping to avoid creating a new table... that table would have 3 columns... id, post_id, state   with 1 - 10 records for each post...  so with as many records as i have would have 300k - well over a million records

Comment: @BigAlRubyNewbie: That's right. An array column wins concerning storage and performance, but you *need* index support. And performance with `int[]` or `smallint[]` beats of `text[]`. The index is much more important here than the type, though. A normalised schema on the other hand allows many other standard features like referential integrity and makes a couple of things easier.