# Create function with loop to be used in UPDATE

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, sql-update

In my Postgres 13 DB I want to update a column `mother_tongues_id` in my table based on name columns.

Names are like "Le Minh Thien" and I want to check if those contain words like 'le' or 'lee' then set nationality to 'Vietnam'. The words check table is some thing like this:

| language | noun |
| --- | --- |
| vietnam | +lee+le+long+la+ |
| chinese | +lu+zhu+ |

Here is my `UPDATE` code:

```
UPDATE resume
SET mother_tongues_id = (
    SELECT id FROM mother_tongues
    WHERE check_language(resume.id) = id
    limit 1);
WHERE mother_tongues_id IS NULL;
```

Here is my `check_language()` function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_language(rid integer) RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
    DECLARE i int = (SELECT (LENGTH(CONCAT(first_name, ' ',last_name)) - LENGTH(replace(CONCAT(first_name, ' ',last_name), ' ', ''))) FROM resume where id = rid);
    DECLARE sname varchar = '';
    DECLARE sid int = 0
    LOOP
        SET i = i - 1;
        SET sname = SELECT split_part(SELECT CONCAT(first_name, ' ',last_name) FROM resume  where id = rid, ' ', i)
        if select id from mother_tongues WHERE noun ILIKE '%+sname+%' then SET sid = id;
        end if;
        IF i = 1 THEN
            EXIT;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    if sid > 0 then RETURN sid;
    else RETURN NULL;
    end if;
END;

$BODY$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I try to create a function in Postgres with loop to split the name and check the words, however always error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function is extremely inefficient, errors aside.
You certainly don't need a function for this to begin with. A plain `UPDATE` with a correlated subquery matching with the [array overlap operator **`&&`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-OPERATORS-TABLE) does the job:

```sql
UPDATE resume
SET    mother_tongues_id = (
    SELECT m.id
    FROM   mother_tongues m
    WHERE  string_to_array(lower(concat_ws(' ', r.first_name, r.last_name)), ' ')
       &&  string_to_array(trim(m.noun, '+'), '+')
    LIMIT  1
    )
WHERE  mother_tongues_id IS NULL;
```

Of course, this is just putting lipstick on a pig. You should really start by fixing your DB schema. As a minimum, convert `mother_tongues.noun` to `text[]`, so we don't have to do it on the fly. And add a GIN index on that column. See:

- [Check if any of a given array of values are present in a Postgres array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20288639/check-if-any-of-a-given-array-of-values-are-present-in-a-postgres-array/20289634#20289634)
- [Check if CSV string column contains desired values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69444480/check-if-csv-string-column-contains-desired-values/69444551#69444551)

Or properly normalize the design.

More fundamentally, deciding nationality based on typical names is a dubious approach. Besides being hardly valid, there can be any number of conflicts, like multiple matches. Currently, `LIMIT 1` simply takes an arbitrary match in this case.

If you really need to loop in a PL/pgSQL function (which you don't in this case), read here:

- [Loop over array dimension in plpgsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783422/loop-over-array-dimension-in-plpgsql/9784986#9784986)
- [Postgres FOR LOOP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145761/postgres-for-loop/19147320#19147320)

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax errors, here is a fix, have a try again.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_language(rid integer) RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
    DECLARE 
        i int = (SELECT (LENGTH(CONCAT(first_name, ' ',last_name)) - LENGTH(replace(CONCAT(first_name, ' ',last_name), ' ', ''))) FROM resume where id = rid);
        sname varchar(255) = '';
        sid int = 0;
    BEGIN
        LOOP
            SET i = i - 1;
            SET sname = (SELECT split_part(CONCAT(first_name, ' ',last_name), ' ', i) FROM resume  where id = rid);
            if select id from mother_tongues WHERE noun ILIKE '%+sname+%' then 
                SET sid = id;
            end if;
            IF i = 1 THEN
                EXIT;
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
        if sid > 0 then 
            RETURN sid;
        else 
            RETURN NULL;
        end if;
    END;
$BODY$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

UPDATE resume
SET mother_tongues_id = (
    SELECT id FROM mother_tongues
    WHERE check_language(resume.id) = id
    limit 1
)
WHERE mother_tongues_id IS NULL;
```