# unique index on embedded json object

Tags: json, postgresql, indexing, unique-index, postgresql-9.4

I am testing Postgresql 9.4 beta2 right now. I am wondering if it is possible to create a unique index on embedded json object?

I create a table name `products`:

```
CREATE TABLE products (oid serial primary key, data jsonb)
```

Now, I try to insert json object into data column.

```
{
    "id": "12345",
    "bags": [
        {
            "sku": "abc123",
            "price": 0,
        },
        {
            "sku": "abc123",
            "price": 0,
        }
    ]
}
```

However, I want `sku` of bags to be unique.  It means the json can't be inserted into products tables because `sku` is not unique in this case.

I tried to create a unique index like below, but it failed.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX product_sku_index ON products( (data->'bags'->'sku') )
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: A unique index won't work here, because there's *only one value*. You can't add multiple entries to an index for a single row. For this you would need a `check` constraint - but that can only operate on a single row. There's no easy way to say "I want this subfield to be unique across all json objects in all rows".

Comment: Please don't use `oid` for your own columns. That is an internal name used by Postgres and will cause lots of confusion (if not problems)

Comment: I think I have to change my design.  Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your attempt to create a `UNIQUE INDEX` on the expression was bound to fail for **multiple reasons**.

<strike>`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX product_sku_index ON products( (data->'bags'->'sku') )`</strike>

The first and most trivial being that ...
<strike>`data->'bags'->'sku'`</strike>
does ***not*** reference *anything*. You could reference the *first* element of the array with

```
data->'bags'->0->>'sku'
```

or shorter:

```
data#>>'{bags,0,sku}'
```

But that expression only returns the first value of the array.
Your definition: *"I want sku of bags to be unique"* .. is unclear. Do you want the value of `sku` to be unique? Within one JSON object or among all json objects in the column `data`? Or do you want to restrict the array to a single element with an `sku`?

Either way, neither of these goals can be implemented with a simple `UNIQUE` index.

#### Possible solution

If you want `sku` **values** to be unique across all json arrays in `data->'bags'`, there is a way. Unnest the array and write all individual `sku` values to separate rows in a simple auxiliary table with a unique (or PK) constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE prod_sku(sku text PRIMARY KEY);  -- PK enforces uniqueness
```

This table may be useful for additional purposes.
Here is a **complete code example** for a very similar problem with plain Postgres arrays:

- [Can PostgreSQL have a uniqueness constraint on array elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016776/can-postgresql-have-a-uniqueness-constraint-on-array-elements/8017013#8017013)

Only adapt the unnesting technique. Instead of:

```
DELETE FROM hostname h
USING  unnest(OLD.hostnames) d(x)
WHERE  h.hostname = d.x;

...

INSERT INTO hostname(hostname)
SELECT h
FROM   unnest(NEW.hostnames) h;
```

Use:

```
DELETE FROM prod_sku p
USING  jsonb_array_elements(NEW.data->'bags') d(x)
WHERE  p.sku = d.x->>'sku';

...

INSERT INTO prod_sku(sku)
SELECT b->>'sku'
FROM   jsonb_array_elements(NEW.data->'bags') b
```

Details for *that*:

- [PostgreSQL joining using JSONB](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/83935/3684)