# How to count rows where an array column contains an element

Tags: java, sql, arrays, database, postgresql

I have a table that has a column `city[]`, so I have:

```
1 city [london]
2 city [london,paris]
```

How can I count the city `london` in my table?

Comment: Do you want to count how many rows contain "london" or how many times "london" appears in one row?

Comment: thank you @RealSkeptic, i want to now how many times "london" appears in all rows

Comment: And is it possible that it appears more than once in a single row?

Comment: no it is not possible

Comment: And how do you implement this constraint? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016776/can-postgresql-have-a-uniqueness-constraint-on-array-elements/8017013#8017013

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To count all the rows in a PostgreSQL table where a certain value appears anywhere in an array, you use the `ANY` function:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cities WHERE 'london' = ANY( city );
```

(This is assuming the table is called `cities`).

The predicate `'london' = ANY( city )` means "Any element in the array `city` is equal to `'london'`". This select the rows that match "london", and then counts them.

Answer (score 2):

If the table is not trivially small you'll want to have a GIN index on the array column. You'll want to use array operators instead of the `= ANY ()` construct to actually use this index:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM cities WHERE '{london}'::text[] <@ city;
```

Details:

- [Check if value exists in Postgres array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231544/check-if-value-exists-in-postgres-array/11231965#11231965)

Comment: it gives me array value must start with "{" or dimension information

Comment: @MostafaJamareh: Sorry, syntax error; fixed.  `<@` expects an *array* on both sides.