# How to constrain that JSON/JSONB values in a column be completely different?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, database-design, unique-constraint

For a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE example (
    totally_unique JSONB
);
```

How can I constrain that values for all keys in `totally_unique` must be different? The keys and values can be any strings, so I can't just write individual constraints for each possible key.

In other words, if `{"a": "one", "b": "two"}` is in the table, I want to prevent inserting `{"a": "one", "b": "three"}` because the value `totally_unique->>'a' = 'one'` already exists.

A `UNIQUE` constraint isn't sufficient for this, but I don't see what kind of constraint or index would work.

Comment: Keys and values are all strings in my actual use case.

Comment: So please make your question fit your situation.

Comment: See also https://blog.hagander.net/json-field-constraints-228/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no built-in method to guarantee unique key/value pairs inside JSON values across the table, neither for `json` nor for `jsonb`.

But you can achieve your goal with a helper table and an index. Only considering the **outermost level** of your JSON values. This is not prepared for nested values.

### Solution for `jsonb`

Requires Postgres 9.4 or later, obviously.
(Works for `json` in Postgres 9.3, too, after minor modifications.)

Table layout

```sql
CREATE TABLE example (
  example_id     serial PRIMARY KEY
, totally_unique jsonb NOT NULL  -- NOT json
);

CREATE TABLE example_key (
  key   text
, value text
, PRIMARY KEY (key, value)
);
```

Trigger function & trigger

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_example_insupdelbef()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   -- split UPDATE into DELETE & INSERT to simplify
   IF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN
      -- Works in pg 9.4+ with jsonb:
      -- Does not work with json since there is no "=" operator for json
      IF OLD.totally_unique IS NOT DISTINCT FROM NEW.totally_unique THEN
         RETURN NEW;  -- exit, nothing to do
      END IF;
   END IF;

   IF TG_OP IN ('DELETE', 'UPDATE') THEN
      DELETE FROM example_key k
      USING  jsonb_each_text(OLD.totally_unique) j(key, value)
      WHERE  j.key = k.key
      AND    j.value = k.value;

      IF TG_OP = 'DELETE' THEN
         RETURN OLD;  -- exit, we are done
      END IF;
   END IF;

   INSERT INTO example_key(key, value)
   SELECT *
   FROM   jsonb_each_text(NEW.totally_unique) j;

   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$;

CREATE TRIGGER example_insupdelbef
BEFORE INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE OF totally_unique ON example
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_example_insupdelbef();
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_15&fiddle=d698e22fed508ece141b4b9b5db8e8f6)* - demonstrating `INSERT` / `UPDATE` / `DELETE`.
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a54376/1)</sub>

The key function to handle `jsonb` is [**`jsonb_each_text()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE), which does exactly what you need, since your values are supposed to be `text`.

Closely related answer for a Postgres array column with more explanation:

- [Can PostgreSQL have a uniqueness constraint on array elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016776/can-postgresql-have-a-uniqueness-constraint-on-array-elements/8017013#8017013)

Also consider the ***"righteous path"*** of normalization laid out there. Applies here as well.

This is not as unbreakable as a `UNIQUE` constraint, since triggers can be circumvented by other triggers and more easily deactivated, but if you don't do anything of the sort, your constraint is enforced at all times.

Note in particular that, [per documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-truncate.html#id-1.9.3.180.7)

> `TRUNCATE` will not fire any `ON DELETE` triggers that might exist for the
> tables. But it will fire `ON TRUNCATE` triggers.

If you plan to `TRUNCATE example`, then make sure you `TRUNCATE example_key` as well, or create another trigger for that.

Performance should be decently good. If your `totally_unique` column holds *many* keys and typically only few change per `UPDATE`, then it might pay to have separate logic for `TG_OP = 'UPDATE'` in your trigger: distill a change set between `OLD` and `NEW`, and only apply that to `example_key`.

Answer (score 6):

If the number of keys is determined and reasonably small, you can create partial unique indexes for all keys.

```
create unique index example_uq_a on example
((totally_unique->'a'))
where (totally_unique->'a') notnull;

create unique index example_uq_b on example
((totally_unique->'b'))
where (totally_unique->'b') notnull;
```

Some checks:

```
test=# insert into example values ('{"a": 1, "b": 2}');
INSERT 0 1

test=# insert into example values ('{"a": 1, "b": 1}');
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "example_uq_a"

test=# insert into example values ('{"a": 2, "b": 2}');
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "example_uq_b"

test=# insert into example values ('{"a": 1}');
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "example_uq_a"

test=# insert into example values ('{"b": 2}');
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "example_uq_b"
```

If the number of keys is not determined, I do not see the possibility of creating constraint. In this case I would create a trigger for insert and update, which would reject values existing in the table.

Comment: Unfortunately the keys could be anything.