# Constrain a numeric array to be sorted and unique

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, database-design, check-constraints

I have a `numeric[]` column in a Postgres database that should represent an array of times (like `{0.5 seconds, 2 seconds, 3.25 seconds, ...}`). As such I would like to constrain the values in the array to be unique and sorted. Is there any way to do that?

I've seen some answers that bring up the `intarray` module's `sort` and `uniq` functions. Is there anything like that for `numeric`/`decimal`?

Answer (score 0):

The additional module `intarray` is for integer only. You cannot use it for data type `numeric` and I wouldn't know of any thing like it for `numeric`, either.

If your numbers have no more than ***n*** fractional digits and can be scaled to integer, you can multiply by ***10^n*** and operate with `integer` instead. Scale back for output ...

Apart from that, I have answered the same question before (sorting is trivial for *sets*):

- [Can PostgreSQL have a uniqueness constraint on array elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016776/can-postgresql-have-a-uniqueness-constraint-on-array-elements/8017013#8017013)