# How do I write a where statement a composite type?

Tags: postgresql

Lets say I create a type such as

```
CREATE TYPE testpair AS (key int, value int);
```

and put it in a table

```
create table test(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, a testpair[]);
```

with these test values

```
insert into test(a) values (ARRAY[(1,2)::testpair]), (ARRAY[(5,9)::testpair]), (ARRAY[(4,16)::testpair]), (ARRAY[(9, 1)::testpair]);
```

I will get a result if I write this

```
select * from test where (4,16)::testpair = ANY(a);
```

How do I write my query if I want to know if any of these pairs start with 4 or for all pairs that are `>= 9`? I know I can write `select ((5,8)::testpair).key;` to get 5 but the following is wrong

```
select * from test where 5  = ANY((a).key);
```

The error given is

```
ERROR:  column notation .key applied to type testpair[], which is not a composite type
```

which makes sense since `a` is an array. But I have no idea how to write the query to use any 'key'

Comment: If you want a key/value "column", why don't you use `hstore`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: It's a simple example. The array is per user

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. A `hstore` will be **much** more efficient to store a list of key/value pairs for a single row (= per user).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I have no idea why hstore would be more efficient nor why this method would be less efficient than any other possible method (assuming I don't need an index)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name "This module implements the hstore data type for storing sets of key/value pairs within a single PostgreSQL value. This can be useful in various scenarios, such as rows with many attributes that are rarely examined, or semi-structured data. Keys and values are simply text strings." 1) keys are ints and unique per user, 2) they are not rarely exampled and not semi structured 3) they are not text strings. Is that good enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `unnest` function, which basically converts an array to a table:

```
select * from test where exists(select 1 from unnest(a) as t where (t).key=5);
```