# Add uniqueness constraint to Postgres text array contents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

Is it possible to add a uniqueness constraint to a Postgres text array? To clarify, I'd like to prevent duplicate instances of the same string in the same array.

I've tried a number of approaches without succes. Here's my most recent attempt:

```
alter table districts add constraint zip_idx exclude using gin (zip_codes with <@);
# access method "gin" does not support exclusion constraints
```

I've found [this](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2014/07/rails-4-and-postgresql-arrays/) solution, which involves introducing a custom function, but I feel like there must be a way to handle this using one of the Gin operators or a contrib module.

Here's a baseline [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/f2b34/1).

Comment: could this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016776/can-postgresql-have-a-uniqueness-constraint-on-array-elements

Comment: @Cyzanfar Thanks. Unfortunately, the accepted answer isn't applicable and the other solution doesn't work on text arrays.

Comment: Got you. will continue to look around see if I can find anything pertinent.