# Simple regex to filter out pre and suffix characters

Tags: sql, arrays, regex, postgresql, database-design

I have a field in my database which has a long list of strings separated by commas. Here are few row examples:

```
HAB
DHAB,RAB,DAB
HAB,RAB,DAB
RAB,HAB, 
RAB,HAB,DAB
```

My query has the following condition:

```
WHERE description LIKE '%HAB%'
```

But it returns the second row which has 'DHAB'.
Can it be done using regex with the `WHERE` statement so that I only get entries which have 'HAB' in the list (one string) and not the entries with 'DHAB'?

Comment: You may use `WHERE description ~ '(^|,)HAB($|,)'`

Comment: Thank you for the response. It is working on the database level. But for some when I test it in regexr.com, it does not include the case where HAB is at the begining of the line or at the end of the line. Is there anything I should be aware of?

Comment: You are testing against a single line with linebreaks there, enable `m` modifier.

Comment: Sorry. I was testing on a string that had multiple \n in it. my bad.

Comment: Yes I will, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
WHERE description ~ '(^|,)HAB($|,)'
```

The regex matches

- `(^|,)` - start of string or a `,`
- `HAB` - literal substring
- `($|,)` - end of string or `,`

See the [**online regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/muGHMw/1).

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are powerful and versatile, but also expensive. Consider a different approach: transform the list to an actual array with [`string_to_array()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) and then:

```
WHERE 'HAB' = ANY (string_to_array(description, ',')
```

Or:

```
WHERE  string_to_array(description, ',') @> '{HAB}'
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=276e38e178b0482dcba7f75b76243d53)*

The latter can be supported with a **GIN index**, which makes it faster by orders of magnitude for big tables.

```
CREATE INDEX ON tbl USING gin (string_to_array(description, ','));
```

Related:

- [Can PostgreSQL index array columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058731/can-postgresql-index-array-columns/29245753#29245753)

Or consider a normalized DB design replacing the comma-separated values with a 1:n relationship. Related:

- [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql/9790225#9790225)
- [Can PostgreSQL have a uniqueness constraint on array elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016776/can-postgresql-have-a-uniqueness-constraint-on-array-elements/8017013#8017013)