# How to add Foreign key constraint on array in PostgreSQL?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, constraints, postgresql-12, postgresql-13

How to add Foreign key constraint on array in PostgreSQL?

look_up table for roles

```
CREATE TABLE party_role_cd
(
  party_role_cd bigint NOT NULL,
  code character varying(80) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT party_role_cd PRIMARY KEY (party_role_cd)
);
```

Party can have zero or many roles [ 0-N relationship ]

```
CREATE TABLE party
(
  party_id biging NOT NULL,
  party_role_cd bigint[] NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT party_id PRIMARY KEY (party_id)
);
```

How to add the `foreign key` constraint for `party_role_cd array` in `party` table?

Comment: This is not possible. Normalise the schema and use a separate table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not implemented in PostgreSQL. Currently, FK constraints only operate on equality between whole column values. No array-to-element references. There is an open TODO item that has been added in 2010. See:

- https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Todo#Referential_Integrity
- https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/1288033876.6278.6.camel@vanquo.pezone.net

There were even attempts to implement it, but never to completion.

Comment: i had a similar Problem.

I am thinking if I have a table:
`id (serial), array(Integers[])`

then I Will have a seperate table: 
`id_of_table1,  array_element (Integer)`


Table 1 & table 2 are always in sync through insert/update/delete Triggers. 
Now array_element is a foreign key of another table. 
In addition I need to make sure each array has unique elements.. I can achieve that by Unique Index on `id_of_table1,  array_element`

Comment: basically a variation of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016776/can-postgresql-have-a-uniqueness-constraint-on-array-elements/8017013#8017013
but uniqueness is Per array in each Row and not throughout the table