# Updating values in PostgreSQL array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have some columns in PostgreSQL database that are array. I want to add a new value (in UPDATE) in it if the value don't exists, otherwise, don't add anytihing. I don't want to overwrite the current value of the array, but only add the element to it.

Is possible do this in a query or I need to do this inside a function? I'm using PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should be as simple as this example for an integer array (`integer[]`):

```
UPDATE tbl SET col = col || 5
WHERE  (5 = ANY(col)) IS NOT TRUE;
```

A `WHERE` clause like:

```
WHERE  5 <> ALL(col)
```

would also catch the case of an empty array `'{}'::int[]`, but fail if a `NULL` value appears as element of the array.

If your arrays never contain NULL as element, consider actual [array operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html), possibly supported by a GIN index.

```
UPDATE tbl SET col = col || 5
WHERE  NOT col @> '{5}';
```

See:

- [Check if value exists in Postgres array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231544/check-if-value-exists-in-postgres-array/11231965#11231965)
- [Can PostgreSQL index array columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058731/can-postgresql-index-array-columns/29245753#29245753)

Comment: `UPDATE token SET grammar = grammar || 'JUNCTION'
WHERE  ('JUNCTION' = ANY(grammar)) IS NOT TRUE;`.

This is the SQL modified for my case, but if fails in the `grammar || 'JUNCTION'`. The type of array is `VARCHAR`.

Comment: Thanks, worked, but a conversion is needed to varchar. `...grammar = grammar || 'JUNCTION'::VARCHAR`.