# Check if value exists in Postgres array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

Using Postgres 9.0, I need a way to test if a value exists in a given array. So far I came up with something like this:

```
select '{1,2,3}'::int[] @> (ARRAY[]::int[] || value_variable::int)
```

But I keep thinking there should be a simpler way to this, I just can't see it. This seems better:

```
select '{1,2,3}'::int[] @> ARRAY[value_variable::int]
```

I believe it will suffice. But if you have other ways to do it, please share!

Answer (score 468, accepted):

Simpler with the **`ANY`** construct:

```
SELECT value_variable = ANY ('{1,2,3}'::int[])
```

The right operand of `ANY` (between parentheses) can either be a [**set** (result of a subquery, for instance)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-ANY-SOME) or an [**array**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.28.16). There are several ways to use it:

- [SQLAlchemy: how to filter on PgArray column types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10344468/sqlalchemy-how-to-filter-on-pgarray-column-types/10344851#10344851)
- [IN vs ANY operator in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34627026/in-vs-any-operator-in-postgresql/34627688#34627688)

**Important** difference: [Array operators (`<@`, `@>`, `&&` et al.)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-OPERATORS-TABLE) expect *array* types as operands and [support GIN or GiST indices](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-types.html) in the standard distribution of PostgreSQL, while the `ANY` construct expects an *element* type as left operand and can be supported with a plain B-tree index (with the indexed expression to the *left* of the operator, not the other way round like it seems to be in your example). Example:

- [Index for finding an element in a JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404055/index-for-finding-element-in-json-array/18405706#18405706)

None of this works for `NULL` elements. To test for `NULL`:

- [Check if NULL exists in Postgres array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34848009/check-if-null-exists-in-postgres-array/34848472#34848472)

Comment: Thanks. Must have skipped that part of manual. This works great. It has a side effect of automatic casting. Ex: SELECT 1::smallint = ANY ('{1,2,3}'::int[]) works. Just make sure to put ANY() on the right side of expression.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Got a problem where my query worked on local, but in heroku was throwing this message `ANY/ALL (array) requires array on right side`, the add of `::int[]` did the charm.

Comment: where S.employee_id <@ ANY ('"+employeeIDsArray+"'::int[]) This returns PSQLException: ERROR: missing dimension value

Comment: @Ramprasad: `s.employee_id <@ '+list_of_employeeIDs+'::int[]` - no `ANY` with the `<@` operator.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Brandstetter Again same error occurs.Here list_of_employeeIDs means list or array? I try to pass scala array variable

Comment: @Ramprasad: List means list. It is *cast* to an array in the example. What I did not make clear: for the `<@` operator both sides have to be an array: `ARRAY[s.employee_id] <@ '+list_of_employeeIDs+'::int[]` [Array syntax examples.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681622/issue-for-insert-using-psycopg/7681837#7681837)

Comment: In my case s.employee_id is not an array it is single int value.I want to check this single employee_id exists in employeeIDsArray

Comment: @Ramprasad: So *make* it an array. If that's still unclear, please ask a *new question* (not comment).

Comment: error syntax in `SELECT  1 = ANY array[1,2]` but not in `SELECT  1 = ANY (array[1,2])`, why?? The manual say nothing (!).

Comment: @PeterKrauss: Because `ANY` requires parentheses, like demonstrated in my answer. Follow the link to the manual for details. It *does* show parentheses.

Comment: Sorry (!), yes... Well, I not understand this PostgreSQL behaviour where `(expression)` *is not the same as* `expression`, there are a guide for "parentheses rules in PostgreSQL"?

Comment: @PeterKrauss: The expression does not require parentheses. `ANY` does. That's all.

Comment: ... OK, sorry, is a "personal indignation", with the lack of logic/coherence or a lack of "manual lighting exceptions" (for the usual parenthesis rules)... [Now I am expressing it as a question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22763940/287948)

Comment: Although this is a dinosaur question in internet years, slow folks like me should be made aware that `'something' = ANY(some_array)` can also be used in a `WHERE` clause. For reasons known only to Crom, I have spent the last four years thinking that I couldn't use array comparators in `WHERE` clauses. Those days are gone now. (I was dropped on my head as a child, so maybe it's just me).

Comment: @GT.: The gist of it: *any* `boolean` expression works in the `WHERE` clause - Crom willing.

Comment: I am trying to do something similar but I am struggling to get the actual array from a value in a table. Defining the array manually woks fine. `IF 'Hello' = ANY (ARRAY['Hello', 'World']::text[]) THEN ...` works but `IF 'Hello' = ANY (SELECT list FROM public."HelloWorldTable" WHERE name = 'HelloWorldList') THEN ...` raises an error. Also tried adding `::text` and `::text[]` but can't get it working. Please help.

Comment: @Kajsa: I get what you are trying to do. But with a *subselect*, `ANY` expects a *set*, not an array. Use instead: `IF EXISTS (SELECT FROM public."HelloWorldTable" WHERE name = 'HelloWorldList' AND 'Hello' = ANY (list)) THEN ...`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31192557/939860 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/11892796/939860 (Also, please ask questions as *question*, not as comment. You can always link to another post for context.)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, Thank you so much. I also wrote a question about this on the database administrator exchange, https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/255308/how-to-check-if-a-value-is-in-an-array-in-a-table
If you could post your answer there I'll be most happy to accept it.
Again, Thank you! Both for the solution and your tips on how to post.

Comment: If you have trouble deciphering this into a normal sql query, here's an example: `SELECT id FROM conversation WHERE 45043182 = ANY(participant_user_ids) ;`

Answer (score 146):

Watch out for the trap I got into: When checking if certain value is not present in an array, you shouldn't do:

```
SELECT value_variable != ANY('{1,2,3}'::int[])
```

but use

```
SELECT value_variable != ALL('{1,2,3}'::int[])
```

instead.

Comment: Kind of a double negative; notice his use of `ALL` vs `ANY`

Comment: `SELECT NOT value_variable = ANY('{1,2,3}'::int[])` might be more readable

Answer (score 48):

> but if you have other ways to do it please share.

You can compare two arrays.  If any of the values in the left array overlap the values in the right array, then it returns true.  It's kind of hackish, but it works.

```
SELECT '{1}'   && '{1,2,3}'::int[];  -- true
SELECT '{1,4}' && '{1,2,3}'::int[];  -- true
SELECT '{4}'   && '{1,2,3}'::int[];  -- false
```

- In the first and second query, value `1` is in the right array
- Notice that the second query is `true`, even though the value `4` is not contained in the right array
- For the third query, no values in the left array (i.e., `4`) are in the right array, so it returns `false`

Comment: how can I search for a column from another table to have a value in the array?

e.g. select * from beers where style_id in (select preferences from users where id=1) limit 1;

style_id is an integer data type; preferences is integer[]

I get this error

ERROR: operator does not exist: integer = integer[] LINE 1: select * from beers where style_id in (select preferences f... ^ HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: @HP There are different ways to solve that question, you should ask a new question

Comment: are you sure there is no existing question ? @vol7ron

Comment: @HP Not at all, but comments are for comments concerning a question or answer; typically to add more information or solicit more information that wasn't addressed.  You're asking a question that is not related to this answer.  I think you will have more luck by asking your question as a new post, not in the comment ;)

Comment: @HP if you haven't posted your question you can see here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/144cd/3 for an example of what you need to do -- your issue is different because you need to unnest your array.

Answer (score 12):

**`unnest`** can be used as well. 
It expands array to a set of rows and then simply checking a value exists or not is as simple as using `IN` or `NOT IN`.

e.g.

1. **id** => uuid
2. **exception_list_ids** => uuid[]

`select * from table where id NOT IN (select unnest(exception_list_ids) from table2)`

Comment: Yes. Note that in my query plans SELECT UNNEST is not as good as = ANY.  I'd recommend checking the query plans to see if you get what you want / expect.

Answer (score 11):

Hi that one works fine for me, maybe useful for someone

```
select * from your_table where array_column ::text ilike ANY (ARRAY['%text_to_search%'::text]);
```

Answer (score 10):

"Any" works well. Just make sure that the any keyword is on the right side of the equal to sign i.e. is present after the equal to sign.

Below statement will throw error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "any"

```
select 1 where any('{hello}'::text[]) = 'hello';
```

Whereas below example works fine

```
select 1 where 'hello' = any('{hello}'::text[]);
```

Comment: this should be a much more highly upvoted answer. It also clarifies that the type is text[] and not string[] which a great many ppl might assume IF they have experience with other programming languages

Answer (score 4):

When looking for the existence of a element in an array, proper casting is required to pass the SQL parser of postgres.  Here is one example query using array contains operator in the join clause:

For simplicity I only list the relevant part:

```
table1 other_name text[]; -- is an array of text
```

The join part of SQL shown

```
from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.other_name::text[] @> ARRAY[t2.panel::text]
```

The following also works

```
on t2.panel = ANY(t1.other_name)
```

I am just guessing that the extra casting is required because the parse does not have to fetch the table definition to figure the exact type of the column.  Others please comment on this.

Answer (score 0):

An additonal note to the accepted answer by @ErwinBrandstetter: If you want to take advantage of an index on the array column when comparing to a singe value, you can wrap your value in an array like this:

`select '{1,2,3}'::int[] @> ARRAY[value_variable]`

You may need to cast the array type when used parameters though:

`select '{1,2,3}'::int[] @> ARRAY[@value_variable]::int[]`