# Postgresql Select from values in array

Tags: arrays, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

i am converting multiple rows in to a array using array_agg() function,
and i need to give that array to a select statements where condition.

My query is,

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 
  ALL(SELECT array_agg(id) FROM table WHERE some_condition)
```

but it gives error, how can i over come it..

Comment: what is the error you are getting??

Comment: ERROR:operator does not exist: bigint = bigint[]                  HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the error has been cleared by type casting the array, using my query like this

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 
    ALL((SELECT array_agg(id) FROM table WHERE some_condition)::bigint[])
```

[reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231544/check-if-value-exists-in-postgres-array)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are over-complicating things. As far as I can tell, your query should be equivalent to simple:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE some_condition
```

Or, if you are selecting from 2 different tables, use join:

```
SELECT table1.*
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
WHERE some_condition
```

Not only this is simpler, it is also faster than fiddling with arrays.

Comment: i need to take the count of the records,

Comment: this was not mentioned in your question. what's wrong with `SELECT count(*) ...`?