# Check if value exists in postgres array for partitioning via check constraint

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231544/check-if-value-exists-in-postgres-array) very similar question but all of the answer started with a 'select' statement. I want to check whether a string is contained in a constant array with about 30 other strings. I could write a long `x == a OR x == b OR...` statement but I thought there might be a cleaner way.

So this doesn't work as a constraint check: `SELECT language = ANY ('{"en", "pt", "es", "fr"}'::text[])`

Comment: Just remove the `select` then it should work in a check constraint.

Comment: This works, thanks for that. But this ANY function seems to be too complex for postgres to automatically ignore for selects on partitioned tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just removing the SELECT works:

```
CHECK(
    language = ANY ('{"en", "pt", "es", "fr"}'::text[])
)
```

But as a_horse_with_no_name pointed out:

Not using an array is even better, as this does not break the partitioning optimization.

```
CHECK(
    not( language in ('en', 'pt', 'es'))
)
```

Now `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE language='de';` will not even look at this table.

Comment: I don't see a reason why you need an array at all: Just use `check (language in ('en', 'pt', 'es', 'fr'))`

Comment: That is indeed much better. The Array actually broke the partitioning optimization.