# Postgres check constraint on `TEXT[]` using a normalized solution

Tags: arrays, postgresql, check-constraints

Similar to other questions asked but haven't found a normalized solution for `TEXT[]`:

[Postgres check constraint in text array for the validity of the values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57111636/postgres-check-constraint-in-text-array-for-the-validity-of-the-values)

- does not use another table as a check

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/250659/constrain-array-values-to-an-allowed-set-of-values

- same solution as above but mentions a normalized solution

[Check if value exists in postgres array for partitioning via check constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31695205/check-if-value-exists-in-postgres-array-for-partitioning-via-check-constraint)

- similar

[Postgres ENUM data type or CHECK CONSTRAINT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10923213/postgres-enum-data-type-or-check-constraint)

- great answer and is a normalized solution but only for `TEXT`, not `TEXT[]`

---

I have two tables `articles` and `valid_tags`. `valid_tags` holds text values that are only allowed. When an article is `INSERT`ed the `tags  TEXT[]` column must be an array of valid tag values. I need to check those values against the `valid_tags` table.

```
CREATE TABLE articles (
  tags TEXT[]
);

CREATE TABLE valid_tags (
    name TEXT
);
```

I'm looking for a very similar solution as [Postgres ENUM data type or CHECK CONSTRAINT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10923213/postgres-enum-data-type-or-check-constraint) but with the constraint that column `color_id` is TEXT[].

Comment: If you want relational constraints you should follow relational practices. Normalise your tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normalized and recommended solution is *not* to use an array, but a junction table between your tables. That would solve the problem implicitly.

Note that while you *can* write a check constraint that seems to do what you want, that check constraint is illegal and [will break your database](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/bad-check-constraints-postgresql/) sooner or later. Don't do it.