# Select rows where an postgresql array does not contain a certain value, using WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In the following example the column `parents` is an `array` of `int` (`parents INT[]`).

If I want to select all rows in which the array of `parents` contains `42`, I can run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM records WHERE 42 = ANY (parents);
```

Now I want to do the opposite and select each row in which `parents` does *not* contain `42`.

I tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM records WHERE 42 != ANY (parents);
```

without luck... Does anyone know how this can be done?

I'm using Postgresql `10.3`.

Comment: `42 <> ALL(parents)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM records WHERE NOT (42 = ANY (parents))
```

**Demo**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/394c0/1

Answer (score 0):

check example.
Reference -> [Refrence link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231544/check-if-value-exists-in-postgres-array)

```
SELECT value_variable = ANY ('{1,2,3}'::int[])
```