# Can I make a join condition that joins if the join key has a particular field?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that has a column with strings formatted like this: `{1,4,5}`. They can be any length and I'd like to join an ID table against any value that has its ID in that string.

This is the first table

```
name     id         count 
apple    {1,3,6}    5
orange   {5,3,1}    3
potato   {8,1,9}    3
```

This is the second table -

```
id2     category
1      foo
2      foobar
3      candy
4      candybar
5      oreo
6      pistachio
```

I'd like a row for every ID listed in the first table that has the category from the second table. I'd like them to look like this -

```
id2 name     id         count 
1 apple    {1,3,6}    5
1 orange   {5,3,1}    3
1 potato   {8,1,9}    3
3 apple    {1,3,6}    5
3 orange   {5,3,1}    3
8 potato   {8,1,9}    3
9 potato   {8,1,9}    3
```

This is what I've got so far. Can I have a join filter that says `join if the value is included`?

```
select id2, name, id, count
from table2 as t2 
left join table1 as t1 
on t2.id2 %in% t1.id
```

Comment: String functions are very different from database to database. What specific database are you using? PostgreSQL, Oracle, DB2, etc.

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL.

Comment: For what it's worth, the id field is created from an `array_agg()` function, but I figured I should cast it as text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1) Unsolicited advice**

- I think it's worth considering if you database design (i.e. the way you cut your tables) is really beneficial to your cause. The way the tables are currently set up, is violating Codd's [1st Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) of database design. Consider changing your design to express an n:m relationship between the objects in `FirstTable` and `SecondTable`
- Have names valid in the context of the table. Instead of having `id2` in one table and `id` in another, just name both `id`. In your queries you can refer to them as `firsttable.id` and `secondtable.id` to distinguish them.

**2) Actual answer**

Yes, it is possible but (as also pointed out by the commentors) depends on the database system you use.

If `firststable.id` **is an array** in PostgreSQL, the following query should work:

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    first
JOIN
    second
ON
    second.id = ANY(first.ids);
    -- Took the liberty to change the column names
```

This [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/262e1/6) provides a working example.

If `firsttable.id` **is a string** then you can cast the string to an array using '{42, 23, 17}'::int[] as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231544/check-if-value-exists-in-postgres-array):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    first
JOIN
    second
ON
    second.id = ANY(first.ids::int[]);
```

This [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/cc112/2) gives a working example in case it's a string.

Comment: I would agree with you if the values like `{1,2,3}` were arrays of ints. However, it seems they are `VARCHAR`.

Comment: Wouldn't the second SQLFiddle then handle this properly?

Comment: I'll adapt answer to make that more explicit.

Comment: I think that would work. +1 for the effort. I would encourage you to use modern join syntax.

Comment: Thx! I was unsure if cross-join or left join would be more appropriate. What is the reason for your suggestion? Improved readibility? :)

Comment: Modern join syntax separates join predicates (in the `JOIN` clause) from filtering predicates (in the `WHERE` clause). That greatly improves readability, debuging, and also makes it a lot easier to tackle query performance.

Comment: Not sure about the whole VARCHAR thing, but this did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see the PostgreSQL when I first started to solve this.

You can try the following, but no guarantees if Postgre does not have all the functions.

```
SELECT * FROM (
     SELECT 
         Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS ID2  
         ,A.Name, A.ID, A.[Count]
     FROM  
     (
         SELECT Name, [Count], ID,  
             CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ID,'{',''),'}',''), ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data  
         FROM [StackOver].[dbo].[SplitKey]
     ) AS A CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
 ) as B  
 Left Join [StackOver].[dbo].[SplitKeyID2] as C
 On B.ID2 = C.ID2
  Where C.Category > ''
 Order By B.ID2, B.name
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty convinced there's a better solution that doesn't involve the `GROUP BY` and `ARRAY_AGG()`, but since you are already there, I think this query may help you:

```
select
  t2.id2,
  t2.category,
  t1.id,
  t1.count
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on (
     position ('{' || t2.id2 || '}' in t1.id) <> 0
  or position ('{' || t2.id2 || ',' in t1.id) <> 0
  or position (',' || t2.id2 || ',' in t1.id) <> 0
  or position (',' || t2.id2 || '}' in t1.id) <> 0
)
```