# SQL query, which search all rows with specific items of array column

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

my sql case in `postgres:9.6` database

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    numbers INT []
);

INSERT INTO my_table (numbers) VALUES ('{2, 3, 4}');
INSERT INTO my_table (numbers) VALUES ('{2, 1, 4}');

-- which means --
test=# select * from my_table;
 id | numbers 
----+---------
  1 | {2,3,4}
  2 | {2,1,4}
(2 rows)
```

I need to find all rows with numbers `1` and/or `2`. According [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11231965/10432429) I use query like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE numbers = ANY('{1,2}'::int[]);
```

And got following error:

```sql
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE numbers = ANY('{1,2}'::int[]);
                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

How does correct `sql` query look?

Comment: *"I need to find all rows with numbers 1 and 2"* Which means the expected result is `2 | {2,1,4}` ? As that is the only record where `1` and `2 ` are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `var = ANY(array)` works well for finding if a single value (`var`) is contained in an array.

To check if an array contains parts of another array, you would use the `&&` [operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-OPERATORS-TABLE)

> && -- overlap (have elements in common) -- ARRAY[1,4,3] && ARRAY[2,1] --> true

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE numbers && '{1,2}'::int[];
```

To check if an array contains all members of another array, you would use the `@>` operator

> @> -- contains -- ARRAY[1,4,3] @> ARRAY[3,1] --> true

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE numbers @> '{1,2}'::int[];
```

Comment: @YegorZaremba still iam wondering which one you needed, as next time you should also provide expected results.. To make the question more clear.

Comment: @raymond-nijland case with 1 or 2 numbers