# PostgreSql how to declare variable type list

Tags: postgresql, procedure

In PostgreSql procedure, I need to create a list of integers to use in a delete statement, as in the example:

```sql
DELETE FROM appointment_virtual WHERE appointment_id IN (list_delete);
```

I need help with:

How do I declare a list type variable?
I found the following form, but I was unsure if it serves the purpose of the DELETE statement:

```sql
list_delete integer ARRAY;
```

How do I add items to this list variable?
I found the following way:

```sql
list_delete = array_append (_delete, _appointment_id);
```

How to zero the contents of this list variable?
Is the syntax below correct?

```sql
list_delete = [];
```

Thanks any help!

Comment: Did you have a read of https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html?

Comment: No, `[]` is not correct. Use either `ARRAY[]` or `'{}'`.

Comment: Also see [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11231544/1048572) for the syntax in the `WHERE` clause: it's either `appointment_id = ANY(list_delete)` or `appointment_id IN unnest(list_delete)`.

Comment: ```IN``` cannot be used with arrays. Use ```appointment_id = ANY(list_delete)``` instead.

Comment: @Islingre Thank you!  It'is correct.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To define an array variable append `[]` to the end of the data type:

```
list_delete integer[];
```

To assign values use

```
list_delete := array[1,2];
```

to append an integer to the array:

```
list_delete := list_delete||4;
```

To assign an empty array use:

```
list_delete := CAST(array[] AS integer[]);
```

Or set it to null

```
list_delete := null;
```