# Transform Value in a Column(array Datatype) based on the Array list's Value in a PostgreSQL Query

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I need your help on Postgresql query logic

Say I have a Table

Environment Info:
**AWS Aurora Postgresql db 10.6.x**

```
CREATE TABLE test_table
(id               character varying(50)
name              character varying(128) 
original_value    ARRAY
);
```

Table with values

```
 id                   name             original_value
O1S000000000301       Screw            {metal_fabtication_c,cabinetery_andor_shelves_c,table_c}
O1S000000000302       wrench           {carpentry_c,handyman_c}
O1S000000000303       impact_driver    {carpentry_c,masonry_c,handyman_c}
```

Transformed_value is not a table but it has Name and its corresponding Transformation as below

```
Name                        Value
metal_fabrication_c         Metal Fabrication
cabinetry_andor_shelves_c   Cabinetry/Shelving
handyman_c                  Handyman
carpentry_c                 Carpentry
masonry_c                   Masonry
table_c                     Furniture
```

I have to Write a Query in which Original_value should get this equivalent transformed_Value.

```
SELECT id, name, original_value as transformed_value 
 FROM test_table 
WHERE id IN('O1S000000000301','O1S000000000302','O1S000000000303')
```

The result should be the following

```
id                    name             transformed_value
O1S000000000301       Screw            Metal Fabrication,Cabinetry/Shelving,Furniture
O1S000000000302       wrench           Carpentry,Handyman
O1S000000000303       impact_driver    Carpentry,Masonry,Handyman
```

Comment: So where does `'Metal Fabrication'` come from?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `WITH` clause for this scenario

try in this way:

```
with cte(name, value) as (
values
('metal_fabtication_c', 'Metal Fabrication'),
('cabinetery_andor_shelves_c', 'Cabinetry/Shelving'),
('handyman_c', 'Handyman'),
('carpentry_c', 'Carpentry'),
('masonry_c', 'Masonry'),
('table_c', 'Furniture')
),

cte1 as 
(
select id, name, unnest(original_value) as "original_value" from test_table where id in ('O1S000000000301','O1S000000000302','O1S000000000303')
)

select 
t1.id,
t1.name, 
array_agg(t2.value) as "transformed_value"
from cte1 t1 left join cte t2 on t2.name=t1.original_value
group by 1,2
```

Above is returning transformed value in `ARRAY`. if you want comma separated values then you use `string_agg(t2.value,',')` instead of `array_agg(t2.value)`

Also if you want any new transformed key value pair then you can add in first `WITH` Block

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pvt49XMd1mumAs8NDjXwmd/1)

Comment: @Akilesh Mishra Thanks very much, your solution was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this second data "Transformed_value " as a table, and fixing some mistakes that I believe to be typo (metal_fabrication_c/metal_fabtication_c).

It is possible to break the array with the [unnest(anyarray)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/functions-array.html), and reference the data with the transformed values ​​table, and then aggregate the data again with [string_agg(expression, delimiter)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/functions-aggregate.html), thus arriving at what I believe to be your need.

```
with reference as (
select 
    tt.id,tt.name,unnest(tt.original_value) as original 
from test_table tt
)
select 
    r.id,
    r.name,
    string_agg(r.original,',') as original,
    string_agg(tv.value,',') as transformed 
from reference r
left join transformed_value tv on tv.name = r.original
group by r.id,r.name
```

[image]

Complete code you can check here: [DBFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/shWef49g6UtQQvK7zY1BVt/0)

Comment: Thanks J.Sperandino, Second Data is not a table, I tried a Case statement,                                                                                                        SELECT CASE
         WHEN (SELECT UNNEST(ARRAY[original_value])) = 'metal_fabrication_c' THEN  'Metal Fabrication'
       END AS test_Array  
FROM test_table  WHERE id = 'O1S000000000301';                  
 I get an** " ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression" **

Comment: You can't load the second data into a temp table to accomplish the desired situation ?
If not , what is the second data ?

Comment: How can I create a Temp table in a SQL query, Sorry I thought if i have to go that route then this should be Procedure of Function in PostgreSQL, sorry new to PostgreSQL

Comment: First aswering the first comment:
The problem behind your try is unnest function  return more than one row , and you are comparing with one unique value, to work with array comparation you can user the word ANY check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231544/check-if-value-exists-in-postgres-array

Comment: Temporary tables exist in the context of the execution of your session, when finished it will be deleted,
to create one just add the word TEMPORARY or TEMP after CREATE [TEMP / TEMPORARY] TABLE

Comment: Could you Please let me know How will you use case statement and ANY Check SELECT CASE
            WHEN 'metal_fabrication__c' = ANY(original_value) THEN 'Metal Fabrication' 
            WHEN 'cabinetry_andor_shelving__c' = ANY(original_value) THEN 'Cabinetry/Shelving'  WHEN 'Table__c' = ANY(original_value) THEN 'Furniture'               
  
END AS array_test    
FROM test_table 
WHERE  id = 'O1S000000000301'; This still translates the 1st value in the array

Comment: I don't think using CASE is the best solution , I advise you to use my solution by creating a temp table, or use a WITH as in @Akhilesh Mishra's answer see :
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/queries-with.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems you simply want to replace `_` with underscored, make every first word upper case and remove the trailing `_c`. If that is true (and `fabtication` is a type), you can use a combination of `replace`, regexp_replace`and`initcap()`

```
select id, name, 
       string_agg(initcap(replace(regexp_replace(ov, '_c$', ''), '_', ' ')), ',' order by x.idx) as value
from test_table t
   cross join unnest (original_value) with ordinality as x(ov,idx)
where id IN ('O1S000000000301','O1S000000000302','O1S000000000303')   
group by id, name;
```

Comment: Thanks I thought the same, most of the times the Transformed Value follow the Logic, but at times The transformed value will different Say here (Table__c is transformed as FURNITURE and etc)