# postgres npgsql How can I make integer array work correctly

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I have a simple sql query that can take in multiple arrays of type Integer, if I do something like this it works **r.userid in(36,37,38)** I left out some of the code since everything works correctly unless I try to pass it in as a List . I am new to npgsql so I am sure I am missing something any suggestions would be great .

**This works**

```
select s.post,s.fullname,s.location,s.streetplace,s.streetplace_id,s.profile_id as 
    ,s.link,s.title FROM streams s JOIN reshares r on r.userid in(36,37,38)
```

however if I do something like this

**This does not work**

```
var newList = new List<int>{ 36,37,38 };

   select s.post,s.fullname,s.location,s.streetplace,s.streetplace_id,s.profile_id as 
        ,s.link,s.title FROM streams s JOIN reshares r on r.userid in(@following)
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@following", newList);
```

I get the error

42883: operator does not exist: integer = integer[]    at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.

No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if value exists in Postgres array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231544/check-if-value-exists-in-postgres-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PostgreSQL, the `IN` operator is for rows, not arrays; to accomplish the same with arrays, you can use the ANY construct: `WHERE x = ANY(@array)`.

Consult the full PostgreSQL docs [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html).

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what was needed and will also look at docs.