# Express-Postgres fails to apply array filter: error: operator does not exist: integer[] && text[]

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, express

The same query works on the terminal. But for some reason I'm getting an error:

> ```
> operator does not exist: integer[] && text[]
> ```

`pg.query` is unable to process the expression `path && Array[$1]`
using this: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/functions-array.html

```js
exports.getReplies = async function (commentID) {
  commentID = parseInt(commentID);
  console.log(commentID);
  return await db.query(
    `
      WITH RECURSIVE cte (comment_id, body, user_id, path, reply_to, depth)  AS (
          SELECT  comment_id,
              body,
              user_id,
              array[comment_id] AS path,
              reply_to,
              1 AS depth
          FROM    comments
          WHERE   reply_to IS NULL
      
          UNION ALL
      
          SELECT  comments.comment_id,
              comments.body,
              comments.user_id,
              cte.path || comments.comment_id,
              comments.reply_to,
              cte.depth + 1 AS depth
          FROM    comments
          JOIN cte ON comments.reply_to = cte.comment_id
          )
          SELECT comment_id, body, user_id, path, depth FROM cte
      WHERE path && Array[$1] AND comment_id != $2
      ORDER BY path;
      `,
    [commentID, commentID]
  );
};
```

Comment: You are linking to the manual of the outdated Postgres 9.2. Surely you are using a more modern version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```sql
exports.getReplies = async function (commentID) {
  commentID = parseInt(commentID);
  console.log(commentID);
  return await db.query(
      `
      WITH RECURSIVE thread AS (
         SELECT comment_id, body, user_id
              , ARRAY[comment_id] AS path
              , reply_to
              , 1 AS depth
         FROM   comments
         WHERE  reply_to IS NULL

         UNION ALL
         SELECT c.comment_id, c.body, c.user_id
              , t.path || c.comment_id
              , c.reply_to
              , t.depth + 1 -- AS depth
         FROM   thread t
         JOIN   comments c ON c.reply_to = t.comment_id
         )
      SELECT comment_id, body, user_id, path, depth
      FROM   thread
      WHERE  $1::int = ANY(path)    -- !!!
      AND    comment_id <> $2::int
      ORDER  BY path;
      `,
    [commentID, commentID]
  );
```

#### Why?

Short answer: **type resolution**.

Long answer:

Concluding from the error message that `comments.comment_id` is of type `integer`. Forming an array from it with `ARRAY[comment_id]` produces an integer array: `integer[]`, or `int[]` for short.

You want `int[]` or compatible on the other side, not `text[]`. **Untyped string literals** are passed (I assume, but the solution also works for parameters typed `text` or `varchar`). When fed to the [ARRAY constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS) in `ARRAY[$1]`, type resolution is forced **before** a matching type can be deferred from the assignment in the expression. The default type is `text`, so you get `text[]`. Hence the error message:

> ```
> error: operator does not exist: integer[] && text[]
> ```

Explanation by example:

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ab7c6747baa84392b87c3de1ac67e9cf)*

You can *fix* this with an explicit cast, either before or after the ARRAY constructor is applied. But it's slightly cheaper to do it first.

```
WHERE  path && ARRAY[$1::int]
```

Then again, my alternative, equivalent syntax is cheaper, yet:

```
WHERE  $1::int = ANY(path)
```

Also, if `comments.comment_id` can be NULL (which you also did not specify) or the recursive CTE adds a NULL to the array (the one at hand does not), your original expression with the [ARRAY "overlap" operator `&&`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-OPERATORS-TABLE) would fail as it cannot cope with NULL elements. So twice better.

The array operator would make sense to employ a GIN index on an array column. But a derived array column is never indexed, so there is no point in using the more expensive operator. See:

- [Check if value exists in Postgres array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231544/check-if-value-exists-in-postgres-array/11231965#11231965)

I added explicit casts to `integer` for both parameters. Does not hurt, but it's *not necessary* in my version of the query - **if** parameters are passed as untyped string literals (which I assume).