# Check if CSV string column contains desired values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to PostgreSQL and I want to split string of the following format:

```
0:1:19
```

with `:` as delimiter.  After split, I need to check if this split string contains either 0 or 1 as a whole number and select only those rows.

For example:

Table A

| Customer | role |
| --- | --- |
| A | 0:1:2 |
| B | 19 |
| C | 2:1 |

I want to select rows which satisfy the criteria of having whole numbers 0 or 1 in role.

Desired Output:

| Customer | role |
| --- | --- |
| A | 0:1:2 |
| C | 2:1 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert to an array, and use the [overlap operator `&&`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-OPERATORS-TABLE):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  string_to_array(role, ':') && '{0,1}'::text[];
```

To make this fast, you could support it with a GIN index on the same expression:

```
CREATE INDEX ON tbl USING GIN (string_to_array(role, ':'));
```

See:

- [Can PostgreSQL index array columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058731/can-postgresql-index-array-columns/29245753#29245753)
- [Check if value exists in Postgres array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231544/check-if-value-exists-in-postgres-array/11231965#11231965)

Alternatively consider a proper one-to-many relational design, or at least an actual array column instead of the string. Would make index and query cheaper.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `LIKE` here:

```sql
SELECT Customer, role
FROM TableA
WHERE ':' || role || ':' LIKE '%:0:%' OR ':' || role || ':' LIKE '%:1:%';
```

But you should generally avoid storing CSV in your SQL tables if your design would allow for that.