# How to match an element in an array of enum value?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, enums

I have a table `books` with rows as below:

The genres field is an **array of enum** that contains the book genre, and these are its possible values: `['adventure', 'horror', 'romance']`

| title | genres |
| --- | --- |
| Deadlock | {Horror} |
| Sunny Hills | {Romance, Adventure} |
| Exiled Prince | {Adventure} |

I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM books
WHERE genres = ARRAY['Adventure']::book_genres_enum[];
```

But that only returns the 'Exiled Prince' book.
How do I formulate a query for all rows *containing* 'Adventure' in its `genres` array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple query is with `= ANY`:

```sql
SELECT * FROM books
WHERE  'Adventure'::book_genres_enum = ANY(genres)
```

This works with any type of array. Nothing special about an `enum` type in this regard. See:

- [Check if value exists in Postgres array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231544/check-if-value-exists-in-postgres-array/11231965#11231965)

The explicit cast is optional. When passing 'Adventure' as untyped string literal, the data type is derived from context. (May not work with typed values.)

#### Index

If the table is big and you have a GIN index on `books(genres)`, use array operators instead. This query is equivalent:

```sql
SELECT * FROM books
WHERE  genres @> '{Adventure}'::book_genres_enum[];
```

Why?

- [Can PostgreSQL index array columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058731/can-postgresql-index-array-columns/29245753#29245753)

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know regular array operators worked with enum types.

Comment: @GashioLee: They do because they work with *any* type.