# Get Other Items in PSQL Array

Tags: arrays, postgresql, psql

I see a few [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231544/check-if-value-exists-in-postgres-array) on here outlining how to use the `any` function to find if a value exists in an array, but I haven't found one to go the other direction. If I have a PSQL array with the values `{see,tom,run,fast}` and I wanted all values except `run`, how would I select the remaining words minus `run`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the documentation for [array functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html). What you are looking for is the `array_remove()` function.

```
select array_remove(array['see','tom','run','fast'], 'run');
```