# Select rows with condition array containing value (value in here, it is data which user typed)

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I have data with column name `authors` type `text[]` like that: `["Mad Snail", "Jiang Ruotai"]`. I am using postgres and typeorm for doing it.

I want to select rows with condition field authors containing values that the user typed. I try to search gg but I got nothing.

For instance, the user typed: Jiang Ruotai. I will get rows with condition authors containing Jiang Ruotai.

How can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if value exists in Postgres array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231544/check-if-value-exists-in-postgres-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `ANY` operator. For example, if the variable`search_term` holds the user's input, then `search_term = ANY(authors)` is `TRUE` when `search_term` matches any of the author's names in the text array.