# For each array element, count rows whose array column contains it

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, query-optimization

In table `users`, there is a column `user_ids varchar[]` with GIN index. Each `user_id` of column `user_ids` in each row is unique.

I want to count the number of rows that contain `user_id` for each `user_id` in an input list.

I try using this query but `EXPLAIN` shows it doesn't use GIN index:

```sql
SELECT user_id, count(*) + 1 COUNT
FROM (
    SELECT unnest(user_ids) user_id
    FROM users 
    WHERE user_ids && ARRAY['1', '2', '3']::varchar[]
) sub
WHERE user_id = ANY(ARRAY['1', '2', '3']::varchar[])
GROUP BY user_id;
```

Is there any way to make use of GIN index here?

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions, your index definitions, and the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For small input arrays and limited overlap between rows, this query should be as fast as it gets:

```sql
SELECT i.user_id, u.*
FROM   unnest('{1, 2, 3}'::varchar[]) i(user_id)  -- your input here
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT count(*) AS count
   FROM   users u
   WHERE  u.user_ids @> ARRAY[i.user_id]  -- !
   ) sub;
```

Notable difference: my query includes elements of the input with 0 matches, your original does not.

The [array operator `@>`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-OPERATORS-TABLE) expects array types as left *and* right operand (even if it's just a single element to the right like in this case).

Array operators can use a GIN index on `(user_ids)`. The subquery in your original query also qualifies for index usage!

See:

- [Check if value exists in Postgres array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231544/check-if-value-exists-in-postgres-array/11231965#11231965)
- [Can PostgreSQL index array columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058731/can-postgresql-index-array-columns/29245753#29245753)

#### Why does my query plan not use the GIN index?

Maybe Postgres decides for a different query plan because the filter is not selective enough, or column statistics are outdated?

To determine whether the index is applicable at all, run a test with this local setting (only in your session!):

```
SET enable_seqscan = off;

EXPLAIN ....
```

This forces a plan without sequential scan if at all possible.

Comment: If that does not clear things up, provide the result of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS) SELECT ...`, an exact `CREATE TABLE` statement, cardinalities, your Postgres version, some sample rows, and sample input in the question.

Comment: We had a similar situation a while back and using the `ANY` construction turned out to be much faster than the `@>` one... YMMV, things are never B&W in SQL =)

Comment: @deroby The `ANY` construct is often faster when not involving an index. For the case at hand, if the table isn't trivially small and the input is selective, a GIN index typically beats the rest (by far).

Comment: Postgres uses index when using your query or `SET enable_seqscan = off;` with some improvement in performance. 
But exactly as you predicted, when input array is larger (around 100 elements in my case), seq scan brings better result.
Your answer is very helpful and enlightening. Thanks