# postgreSQL query only users that their id is in the array

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, reactjs, postgresql

I'm using postgreSQL as my database for node.js app, I'm given an array of id's for example ["1","2","3"], and I want to query only users that their id is include in this array
so it going like this

```
        if (ids){
            users = await pool.query(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN ($1:csv)`, [members])
        }
```

I'm using pool.query on nodejs, but this command shown here is not working so I don't exactly knows how to do that, thanks for any help

Comment: try one of these https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231544/check-if-value-exists-in-postgres-array

Comment: 1) What is `:csv` supposed to be doing? 2) Have you tried `... WHERE id =  ANY($1)`?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver 1) Idk actually,  2) Thanks it is work

Answer (score 2):

This works if you are using the node-postgres npm module for data queries.

So after creating a Pool, use the following query structure:

```
const query = "
  SELECT *
  FROM abc
  WHERE id IN (${ids.map((_, i) => `$${i + 1}`).join(',')});
";
```

and then run the pool.query command passing the query as the parameter.

However please note that the query uses array mapping, and this approach can be a bit expensive.

Comment: I'm actually using pg. but Adrian Klaver comment ```WHERE id =  ANY($1)```
worked