# Search in integer array in Postgres

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

Is there any other way to search for a certain value in an `integer[]` column in Postgres?

My currently installed Postgres version does *not* allow the following statement:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE values *= 10;
```

Array examples:

```
'{11043,10859,10860,10710,10860,10877,10895,11251}'
'{11311,10698,10697,10710,10712,10711,10708}'
```

The statement should return every row where the array contains `'10710'`.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

For equality checks you can simply:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE 10 = ANY (values);
```

Read about [ANY/SOME in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.30.16).
For big tables / big arrays consider [array operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-OPERATORS-TABLE) with **index support**, like:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE values @> '{10}'::int[];
```

See:

- **[Check if value exists in Postgres array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231544/check-if-value-exists-in-postgres-array/11231965#11231965)**
- [IN vs ANY operator in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34627026/in-vs-any-operator-in-postgresql/34627688#34627688)

For integer arrays consider the additional module [`intarray`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/intarray.html):

- [Compare arrays for equality, ignoring order of elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870105/compare-arrays-for-equality-ignoring-order-of-elements/12870508#12870508)

Related:

- [Can PostgreSQL index array columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058731/can-postgresql-index-array-columns/29245753#29245753)
- [Check if value exists in Postgres array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231544/check-if-value-exists-in-postgres-array/11231965#11231965)

Answer (score 7):

quickly search will be so, but you should use index gist or gin for intarray type [Postgres intarray](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/intarray.html)

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE values @> ARRAY[10];
```

Answer (score -2):

```
**Store Integer Array as Strings in Postgresql and Query the Array**    
Finally I could save the integer as string array in one column able to successfully convert into array and query the array using below example.

    CREATE TABLE test
    (
      year character varying,
      id serial NOT NULL,
      category_id character varying,
      CONSTRAINT test_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
    )

    Data
    "2005";1;"1,2,3,4"
    "2006";2;"2,3,5,6"
    "2006";3;"4,3,5,6"
    "2007";7;"1,2"


    select distinct(id) from test, (select id as cid, unnest(string_to_array(category_id ,  ',')::integer[]) as cat from test) c where c.cid=test.id and cat in (1,2,3);

    Result:
    2
    1
    3
    7
```