# Compare arrays for equality, ignoring order of elements

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I have a table with 4 array columns.. the results are like:

```
ids       signed_ids   new_ids   new_ids_signed
{1,2,3} | {2,1,3}    | {4,5,6} | {6,5,4}
```

Anyway to compare `ids` and `signed_ids` so that they come out equal, by ignoring the order of the elements?

Comment: Those arrays aren't equal. Am I correct in guessing that your real question is "how do I compare two PostgreSQL arrays as if they were sets, ie without respect to order?"

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I'm asking for :)

Comment: Question edited to reflect intention.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is sort them and compare them sorted. See [sorting arrays in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12870458/398670).

Given sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE aa(ids integer[], signed_ids integer[]);
INSERT INTO aa(ids, signed_ids) VALUES (ARRAY[1,2,3], ARRAY[2,1,3]);
```

the best thing to do is to if the array entries are always integers is to use the intarray extension, as [Erwin explains in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12870508/398670). It's a *lot* faster than any pure-SQL formulation.

Otherwise, for a general version that works for any data type, define an `array_sort(anyarray)`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION array_sort(anyarray) RETURNS anyarray AS $$
SELECT array_agg(x order by x) FROM unnest($1) x;
$$ LANGUAGE 'SQL';
```

and use it sort and compare the sorted arrays:

```
SELECT array_sort(ids) = array_sort(signed_ids) FROM aa;
```

There's an important caveat:

```
SELECT array_sort( ARRAY[1,2,2,4,4] ) = array_sort( ARRAY[1,2,4] );
```

will be false. This may or may not be what you want, depending on your intentions.

---

Alternately, define a function `array_compare_as_set`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION array_compare_as_set(anyarray,anyarray) RETURNS boolean AS $$
SELECT CASE
  WHEN array_dims($1) <> array_dims($2) THEN
    'f'
  WHEN array_length($1,1) <> array_length($2,1) THEN
    'f'
  ELSE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM unnest($1) a 
        FULL JOIN unnest($2) b ON (a=b) 
        WHERE a IS NULL or b IS NULL
    )
  END
$$ LANGUAGE 'SQL' IMMUTABLE;
```

and then:

```
SELECT array_compare_as_set(ids, signed_ids) FROM aa;
```

This is subtly different from comparing two `array_sort`ed values. `array_compare_as_set` will eliminate duplicates, making `array_compare_as_set(ARRAY[1,2,3,3],ARRAY[1,2,3])` true, whereas `array_sort(ARRAY[1,2,3,3]) = array_sort(ARRAY[1,2,3])` will be false.

Both of these approaches will have pretty bad performance. Consider ensuring that you always store your arrays sorted in the first place.

Comment: Add an alias to your table and brilliant! Thanks :)

Comment: @user766987 Updated with a better definition

Comment: @user766987 ... and updated again with a different approach, just for fun.

Comment: @user766987 Ooh, I forgot to mention the intarray contrib module, which will make all this *hundreds* of times faster.

Comment: Ah, you added `intarray` to your answer. Makes my answer a bit redundant .. except for additional methods.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Yeah, just remembered. You were probably writing yours when I edited :S . Good point on `uniq()` and the operators, it's really useful.

Comment: Yeah, similar idea at the same time at opposite ends of the world .. :)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter You explained the intarray usage much better, removed and pointed to your answer.

Comment: As of postgresql version 12, `LANGUAGE 'SQL' ` will raise the error `UndefinedObject: language "SQL" does not exist`. Dropping the single quotes fixes it.

Answer (score 46):

You can use contained by operator:

```
(array1 <@ array2 and array1 @> array2)
```

Comment: As a postgres arrays newbie, this seems like the best answer.  What are its drawbacks compared to the above?

Comment: Warning! This comparison will only work if all elements are unique:
`select ARRAY[1,2] <@ ARRAY[1,2,2], ARRAY[1,2] @> ARRAY[1,2,2];` will return `true` for both conditions but the arrays do not match (and you can't just add a length check because then you wouldn't be able to differentiate between `[1,2,2]` and `[1,1,2]`

Comment: @JasonAxelson that makes this a great implementation of `array_compare_as_set`, which you would expect to behave exactly as you described :)

Answer (score 20):

The additional module [**intarray**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/intarray.html) provides operators for **arrays of `integer`**, which are typically (much) faster. Install once per database with (in Postgres 9.1 or later):

```
CREATE EXTENSION intarray;
```

Then you can:

```
SELECT uniq(sort(ids)) = uniq(sort(signed_ids));
```

Or:

```
SELECT ids @> signed_ids AND ids <@ signed_ids;
```

**Bold** emphasis on functions and operators from intarray.
In the second example, operator resolution arrives at the specialized intarray operators if left and right argument are type `integer[]`.

Both expressions will ignore order and duplicity of elements. Further reading in the helpful manual [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/intarray.html).

`intarray` operators only work for arrays of `integer` (`int4`), not `bigint` (`int8`) or `smallint` (`int2`) or any other data type.

Unlike the default generic operators, `intarray` operators do not accept NULL values in arrays. NULL in any involved array raises an exception. If you need to work with NULL values, you can **default to the standard, generic operators** by schema-qualifying the operator with the `OPERATOR` construct:

```
SELECT ARRAY[1,4,null,3]::int[] OPERATOR(pg_catalog.@>) ARRAY[3,1]::int[]
```

The generic operators can't use **indexes** with an `intarray` operator class and vice versa.

Related:

- [GIN index on smallint[] column not used or error "operator is not unique"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39798993/gin-index-on-smallint-column-not-used-or-error-operator-is-not-unique/39802812#39802812)

Comment: Is the first solution (using `sort`) faster than the second (using `@>` and `<@`)? If not, I guess I can do without `intarray`.

Comment: @mattdipasquale: I added some more explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If your arrays have **no duplicates** and are of the **same dimension**:

- use array contains `@>`
- AND `array_length` where the length must match the size you want on both sides

Comment: @jason-axelson As stated in the first sentence my answer only applies to arrays without duplicates

Answer (score -1):

> select (string_agg(a,',' order by a) = string_agg(b,',' order by b)) from 
>   (select unnest(array[1,2,3,2])::text as a,unnest(array[2,2,3,1])::text as b) A