# PostgreSQL : compare two arrays, ignore ordering

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I want to compare two arrays, ignoring the order of the elements and duplicates.

I could do a containment check in both directions, but are there better/faster solutions?

```
select * from my_table where my_table.a1 @> my_table.a2 and
                             my_table.a2 @> my_table.a1
```

Comment: If it is one dimensional array of integers with no nulls inside then you can use [intarray](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/intarray.html) to sort its contents, remove duplicates and then compare. I don't know if this will be faster tho. Alternative way is to `unnest` and work with set, this could be faster or slower, depending on your data, conditions and indexes.

Answer (score 3):

From my [internal testing](http://rextester.com/ZPML43022), it seems that these two variants are the fastest (even faster than the `@>` + `<@` check), and they both can handle `NULL`s too:

```
where (select array_agg(distinct e order by e) from unnest(arr1) e)
    = (select array_agg(distinct e order by e) from unnest(arr2) e)

where array(select distinct e from unnest(arr1) e order by e)
    = array(select distinct e from unnest(arr2) e order by e)
```

The latter is usually a little faster, but sometimes not. This can depend on a lot of things, f.ex. the cardinality of the arrays, etc.

Answer (score 1):

**using unnest and distinct example:**

```
t=# create or replace function so62(a1 anyarray,a2 anyarray) returns boolean as
$$
declare
 _r boolean := false;
 _a text;
begin
  with p as (select distinct unnest(a1) order by 1) select array_agg(unnest) into _a from p;
  with p as (select distinct unnest(a2) order by 1) select array_agg(unnest)::text = _a into _r from p;
  return _r;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION
```

*(function updated following @poz notice that it would require two `except` for comparison)*

**test:**

```
t=# with c as (
  select '{1,null,2,2}'::int[] a1,'{2,1,null}'::int[] a2
) 
select a1 @> a2, a2 @> a1,so62(a1,a2) 
from c;
 ?column? | ?column? | so62
----------+----------+------
 f        | f        | t
(1 row)
```

in this example `@>` and `<@` do not work at all.
Also read [Compare arrays for equality, ignoring order of elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870105/compare-arrays-for-equality-ignoring-order-of-elements)

Comment: You'll also need to do the `except` both ways. You're  technically right, **if** the array can contain `NULL` values, this is one of the few possible way to do it, but if it does not contain any `NULL`s, this can also be a [huge performance killer](http://rextester.com/TUBW76742).

Comment: yes, it is - but I assumed nulls from the question, my logic: if not nulls not mentioned, then there can be nulls

Comment: @pozs thanks for your notice! to avoid except twice casting to text