# Find best value - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I generated following Table:

```
  here  | there |      cost
 -------+-------+--------------+
  {1,1} | {1,2} |          0.0 | 
  {1,1} | {2,1} |          0.0 | 
  {1,2} | {1,3} |          1.0 |      
  {2,1} | {2,2} |          1.0 |
  {2,1} | {3,1} |          1.0 |
  {1,2} | {2,2} |          1.0 |      
  {1,3} | {1,4} |          2.0 |       
  {2,2} | {2,3} |          2.0 |       
 ...
  {1,2} | {1,3} |          3.0 |
```

As you can see, I have two different costs for the pair `{1,2}, {1,3}`
How can i manage to keep just the best value for each pair ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will return all unique pairs (here, there) with minimal cost:

```
SELECT
    here,
    there,
    MIN(cost)
FROM
    table_name
GROUP BY
    here,
    there;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to keep the whole row (with more columns), use `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (here, there) *
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY here, there, cost;
```

Related:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Also, since you seem to be using arrays (table definition is undisclosed), careful about non-equality of `'{1,2}'` and `'{2,1}'`. If you need that to evaluate as equal, add your table definition and Postgres version to the question and I'll add a solution. Related:

- [Compare arrays for equality, ignoring order of elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870105/compare-arrays-for-equality-ignoring-order-of-elements/12870508#12870508)