# Aggregate rows to get unique arrays without subsets

Tags: sql, postgresql, merge, concatenation, postgresql-performance

Initial data (actual table contains more than 2,000,000 rows):

```
+--------+--------+-------+
| note   | factor | label |
+--------+--------+-------+
| note_1 | 1      | 2     |
+--------+--------+-------+
| note_1 | 1      | 3     |
+--------+--------+-------+
| note_1 | 2      | 4     |
+--------+--------+-------+
| note_2 | 123    | 2     |
+--------+--------+-------+
| note_2 | 123    | 3     |
+--------+--------+-------+
| note_2 | 2      | 4     |
+--------+--------+-------+
| note_3 | 456    | 4     |
+--------+--------+-------+
| note_4 | 434    | 5     |
+--------+--------+-------+
| note_5 | 456    | 3     |
+--------+--------+-------+
| note_5 | 456    | 4     |
+--------+--------+-------+
```

**What I want to get** (further **final table**):

```
+----+-----------------+
| id | notes           |
+----+-----------------+
| 1  | {note_1,note_2} |
+----+-----------------+
| 2  | {note_4}        |
+----+-----------------+
| 3  | {note_3,note_5} |
+----+-----------------+
```

**More clearly**:

I need to group `notes` by `factor` and `label` columns. Note can be in the result table only once. Result table should contains two columns: `id` - row number, `notes` - array of notes.

I have written a query to group by `factor` and `label`:

```sql
select row_number() over (order by factor) as id
     , array_agg(note order by note) as notes
from test_brand
group by factor, label
```

It gives these results:

```
+---+-----------------+
| 1 | {note_1}        |
+---+-----------------+
| 2 | {note_1}        |
+---+-----------------+
| 3 | {note_2}        |
+---+-----------------+
| 4 | {note_2}        |
+---+-----------------+
| 5 | {note_1,note_2} |
+---+-----------------+
| 6 | {note_4}        |
+---+-----------------+
| 7 | {note_5}        |
+---+-----------------+
| 8 | {note_3,note_5} |
+---+-----------------+
```

But I do not know how to get the final table proceeding from here.

---

If we omit identifiers and return to ordinary numbers, then this task looks like a union of sets (which in fact it is).
Let's say we have 8 sets: {1}, {1}, {2}, {2}, {1,2}, {4}, {5}, {3,5}. We need to get three sets: {1,2}, {4}, {3,5}.

How it happened in my opinion:
Sets {1}, {1}, {2}, {2}, {1,2} merged into one set {1,2}, because there is intersection between {1} and {2} with {1,2}.
Sets {3,5}, {5} merged into one set {3,5}, because there is intersection between {5} and {3,5}.
Set {4} does not intersect with anyone, so it remains as it is.

Answer (score 2):

There may be more efficient ways, but this does it:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT min(rn) AS rn, notes  -- to remove dupes cheaply
   FROM  (
      SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY factor, label) AS rn  -- ORDER BY factor, label?!
           , array_agg(note ORDER BY note) AS notes
      FROM   test_brand
      GROUP  BY factor, label
      ) sub
   GROUP  BY notes
   )
SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY rn) AS rn, notes
FROM   cte c
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM cte c1
   WHERE c1.notes @> c.notes
   AND   c1.rn <> c.rn
   )
ORDER  BY 1;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=09d010eb2fd1ba6c0652ee6470437284)*

After your initial query, remove duplicates in the CTE and remember minimum row number.

In the final `SELECT`, eliminate all rows where the set is contained in another set (except itself). Compact row numbers with another instance of `row_number()`.
Voilá.

#### Optimize performance

> more than 2,000,000 rows.

If `note` can be an **`integer`** instead of the string type, computation will be substantially faster, even more so after installing the additional module [**`intarray`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/intarray.html), which provides a faster implementation of `@>` operator for integer arrays.

If the derived table from the CTE is still big, it might pay to create a temporary table, add an index (and `ANALYZE`!), and run the outer `SELECT` based on that temp table:

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp AS (
   SELECT min(rn) AS rn, notes  -- to remove dupes cheaply
   FROM  (
      SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY factor, label) AS rn
           , array_agg(note ORDER BY note) AS notes
      FROM   test_brand
      GROUP  BY factor, label
      ) sub
   GROUP  BY notes
   );

CREATE INDEX ON tmp USING gin (notes gin__int_ops);
ANALYZE tmp;

SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY rn) AS rn, notes
FROM   tmp c
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM tmp c1
   WHERE c1.notes @> c.notes
   AND   c1.rn <> c.rn
   )
ORDER  BY 1;
```

See:

- [Compare arrays for equality, ignoring order of elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870105/compare-arrays-for-equality-ignoring-order-of-elements/12870508#12870508)
- [Query “all of” across many-to-many relation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/236603/3684)
- [Are regular VACUUM ANALYZE still recommended under 9.1?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/18694/3684)

Comment: thanks for the answer!
I'm not sure, but something went wrong.
You can see run example here: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f8ca7e2ee429e346dfcde8360fd72215)

I just add two new rows: `note_7, 123, 2` and `note_8, 656, 8`. Correct result will be:
{note_1,note_2,note_7}
{note_4}
{note_3,note_5}
{note_8}
But running the script gave the following result:
{note_1,note_2}
{note_2,note_7}
{note_4}
{note_3,note_5}
{note_8}

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter . . . Somehow your starting an answer with "there may be more efficient ways" is cognitively dissonant.  Almost by definition, I expect your answers to be the most efficient way of doing something in Postgres.

Comment: @Moon But `note_1` and `note_7` do not share `(factor, label)`?

Comment: @Gordon: Wasn't so sure of it this time. `@>` is an expensive operation without index. The added bit about optimization made it better for me. Still, I feel like there may be more potential to speed it up. (And, thank you.)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, yes, they are not. But `note_1` share `(factor, label)` with `note_2`, and `note_2` share `(factor, label)` with `note_7`. And than we need to group them all together. In other words: {1}, {1,2}, {2,7} should create set of {1,2,7}.

Comment: @Moon: Well, that's not obvious from your question. Then you need to do more. I am out of time ATM.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, I'll add more rows to the initial data.
I will try my best to find something that can help solve the current problem, but if you have any ideas later, I will be glad to see them. Thank you!

Comment: I think I answered your original question as given. Now you *changed* it into a different (much harder) question. Changing the nature of a question after answers have been given is not the way to go. Start a new question instead please. You can always reference this one for context, and drop a comment here to link forward. I've rolled back your last edit. You can find everything in the edit history.