# postgres - compare jsonb array, ignore order?

Tags: postgresql

How can I exact match jsonb arrays in postgresql (SELECT .. WHERE), whilst ignoring the order of the array?

| id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | `["a", "b"]` |
| 2 | `["b"]` |
| 3 | `["a"]` |
| 4 | `["c", "a", "b"]` |

With the input of `["b", "a"]` I expect to receive id 1, and with the input of `["a", "b", "c"]` I expect to receive id 4. I have tried using the `?&` operator, although it would return id 1, 2, 4 if the input was `["b"]`.

Comment: You can Build a String from the Array. Then you can Check for equal.

Comment: @DenisKohl That *would* depend on the order

Comment: Closely related: [Compare postgres arrays for equality, ignoring order of elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12870105/1048572)

Comment: If using `a ?& b` didn't work, try `a ?& b AND b ?& a`

Answer (score 3):

You should try to use contains operator `@>` in this way:

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_table 
WHERE '["b", "a"]'::jsonb @> data 
  AND data @> '["b", "a", "c"]'::jsonb;
```

If `["b", "a"]` contains `data` and `data` contains `["b", "a"]` then `["b", "a"]` is equal to `data`.

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider this schema and initial data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (
  id serial not null primary key,
  data jsonb
);

INSERT INTO test (data) VALUES 
  ('["a", "b"]'::jsonb),
  ('["b"]'::jsonb),
  ('["a"]'::jsonb),
  ('["c", "a", "b"]'::jsonb);
```

Query would be like:

```sql
SELECT id, data FROM (
  SELECT *, 
  ARRAY(
    SELECT UNNEST(
      ARRAY(SELECT jsonb_array_elements_text(data))
    ) AS item ORDER BY item
  ) AS db_array_sorted, 
  ARRAY(
    SELECT UNNEST(
      ARRAY(SELECT jsonb_array_elements_text('["b", "a"]'::jsonb))
    ) AS item ORDER BY item
  ) AS input_array_sorted 
  FROM test
) AS sq
WHERE db_array_sorted = input_array_sorted;
```

Result of execution:

[image]

I believe, the query is quite self-descriptive. [A DB fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jKYhPMD4aVbAoNsDXoYg4j/0).