How to find intersection of two tables linked indirectly through a many-to-many association?
I have "people <- many-to-many -> tags" association, and "tag_group <- many-to-many -> tags" association. I'm trying to find combinations of people and tag groups which have the same tags selected.

tags



ID
Label




1
Reg


2
Green


3
Dog


4
Cat



tag_groups



ID
Label
Sort




1
Colours
2


2
Animals
3


3
Mix
1



tag_groups_tags



tag_groups.id
tags.id
comment




1
1
(Colours - Red)


1
2
(Colours - Green)


2
3
(Animals - Dog)


2
4
(Animals - Cat)


3
1
(Mix - Red)


3
2
(Mix - Green)


3
4
(Mix - Cat)



people



ID
Name




1
John


2
Jane


3
Pete



people_tags



people.id
tags.id
comment




1
1
John linked to all Tags


1
2
...


1
3
...


1
4
...


2
1
Jane linked to the same tags as Mix group


2
2
...


2
4
...


3
1
Pete linked to only tag Red




Question 1: How could I find the intersection of people and tag_groups - find all people that are tagged with the same tags in each group?
Desired result 1



people.id
tag_groups.id
comment




1
1
John - Colours -> people_tags links John to both Red and Green


1
2
John - Animals -> people_tags links John to both Dog and Cat


1
3
John - Mix -> people_tags links John to all Red, Green and Cat


2
1
Jane - Colours -> people_tags links Jane to both Red and Green, and also Cat, but that's irrelevant to Colours group


2
3
Jane - Mix -> people_tags links Jane to all Red, Green and Cat



-- Pete is not in the result, as people_tags don't link him to enough tags to find a full match with any tag_group
My take on the desired result 1
This would solve it using arrays, CTE syntax for legibility.
WITH people_cte AS (select people_id, array_agg(tags_id) tags from people_tags group by people_id),
     groups_cte AS (select tag_groups_id, array_agg(tags_id) tags from tag_groups_tags group by tag_groups_id),
     combinations AS (SELECT people_id, tag_groups_id
                      FROM people_cte,
                           groups_cte
                      WHERE people_cte.tags @> groups_cte.tags)
SELECT people_id, name, tag_groups_id, label
FROM combinations
         JOIN people ON combinations.people_id = people.id
         JOIN tag_groups ON combinations.tag_groups_id = tag_groups.id;

I’m concerned that it has to first take ALL people and groups to calculate arrays of tags and THEN do overlap. Maybe it’s a good first step, but I must be able to shrink the scope of the people and groups to only those that overlap, ignoring those that can never match.
Am I wrong with my performance concerns? I think I need to find a solution without using arrays.
Question 2: How could I find only the first tag_group that matched, if I sort them by tag_groups.sort ASC?
Desired result 2:



people.id
tag_groups.id
comment




1
3
John - Mix -> people_tags links John to all groups, but Mix has the lowest number


2
3
Jane - Mix -> people_tags links Jane to Colours and Mix, and Mix wins because of the sort value



-- Pete is not in the result, as people_tags don't link him to enough tags to find a full match with any tag_group
Question 3: How could I get the first match (similar to Result 2), but somehow left-join the groups to include all People with null in the tag_groups?
Desired result 3:



people.id
tag_groups.id
coment




1
3
(John - Mix)


2
3
(Jane - Mix)


3
null
(Pete - no matching tag_groups found)




DB Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/14043
And just as a backup, these will get the schema and data in place:
create table tags (id int, label text);
create table people (id int, name text);
create table tag_groups (id int, label text, sort int);
create table tag_groups_tags (tag_groups_id int, tags_id int);
create table people_tags (people_id int, tags_id int);

insert into tags (id, label) values (1, 'Red'), (2, 'Green'), (3, 'Dog'), (4, 'Cat');
insert into people (id, name) values (1, 'John'), (2, 'Jane'), (3, 'Pete');
insert into tag_groups (id, label, sort) values (1, 'Colours', 2), (2, 'Animals', 3), (3, 'Mix', 1);
insert into tag_groups_tags (tag_groups_id, tags_id) values (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 4);
insert into people_tags (people_id, tags_id) values (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 4), (3, 1);


I might be missing something, but would something like this help?
with p_tags (people_id, tags) as (
    select people_id, array_agg(tags_id order by tags_id)
    from people_tags
    group by people_id
),
g_tags (group_id, tags) as (
    select tag_groups_id, array_agg(tags_id order by tags_id)
    from tag_groups_tags
    group by tag_groups_id
)
select *
from p_tags pt
join g_tags gt on (pt.tags = gt.tags);

basically compare arrays of tags grouped by group_id with those grouped by people_id.

Thanks, Florian. This is similar to one of the solutions I came up with (look for "My take on the desired result 1" in the initial question). It goes in the right direction and gets the result I want when using (pt.tags @> gt.tags); at the end. With that said, it also loads all people and all groups to build those arrays that are later compared, and I'm concerned about poor performance. On my computer, it takes 300ms to get the result, and there are only few rows to consider. I'm trying to find another way than using array_agg & comparing those arrays.

I had to user "order by" in array_agg to allow for equality comparison of arrays, as order matters. I saw however another technique using a @> b AND b @> a, if that helps (cf: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42545278/244058)

another random idea could be to use ALL(the_subquery) ? didn't have time to test it out

still, your initial take seems to do far bigger joins compared to my proposition, no? we should compare explain (analyze). Maybe you know about https://explain.dalibo.com/

actually no, your take seems pretty similar, sorry!
