# Mysqli fetch multiple distinct values from rows where given value is in any column

Tags: mysql, mariadb, distinct

I have a data table like this. A more close depiction of data.

```
col0  |  col1 |  col2  |  col3  | col4
======================================
milk  | egg   | juice  |        |
egg   | juice |        |        |
bread | jam   | juice  |        |
wheat | egg   | juice  |        |
jam   | juice |        |        |
```

I want to first search for Juice in all columns and fetch all rows where juice is found. Then I have to fetch the rows with most unique and complete data. In this case it is the first row, since it has the most unique and complete data set with no repeating words. So, from this data if I search for 'juice', then i want this result

```
 milk  | egg   | juice  |
 bread | jam   | juice  |
 wheat | egg   | juice  |
```

I have tried to `GROUP BY` and `DISTINCT` on all column combinations, but i couldn't get desired result.
I used this statement

```
SELECT * FROM `table` 
WHERE `col4` = 'juice' OR`col3` = 'juice' OR `col2` = 'juice' OR `col1` = 'juice' 
group by `col2`,`col1`,`col0`;
```

I would prefer it to be in one statement instead of separate ones too.

Comment: What if there are more than one row with same count of most unique values ? How would you decide the tie-break in that case ?

Comment: This might be easier to do if you stored your column level data in rows instead. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868395/sql-multi-valued-attributes

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya the actual data that i am working with does not allow that. The data would be in similar pattern to the shown data.

Comment: @user2649343 can there be duplicate values across multiple columns ? Or all the values will be unique only ? Also, when there is no value, it is represented as an empty string ? or `NULL` ?

Comment: This kind of problem is indicative of poor design. Consider revising your schema.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya i have edited the data set to depict more accurately the actual data.

Comment: .@Strawberry is right; this is a bad schema; ideally you should have these similar columns (attributes) in different rows. It is a Multi-column Antipattern; and that is why we have to invent weird queries to handle bad schema.

Comment: Spreading an array across columns is asking for trouble.  You found one example of why.  Have a table that lists one food per row.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php) function.

> It returns a string with concatenated non-NULL value from a group.

Comment: could you give an example regarding my query?

Answer (score 0):

If you always have "most complete data" in higher column number (col4 > col3 and etc),

You can simply `LIMIT` result to `1`:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `table` 
WHERE `col4` = 'juice' OR`col3` = 'juice' OR `col2` = 'juice' OR `col1` = 'juice'
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are no duplicate values across multiple columns, and empty columns are represented using `NULL`, then we can utilize the implicit typecasting of boolean into int by MySQL:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM your_table 
WHERE 'juice' IN (col1, col2, col3, col4) 
ORDER BY ( (col1 IS NOT NULL) + 
           (col2 IS NOT NULL) +
           (col3 IS NOT NULL) +
           (col4 IS NOT NULL) ) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

**Result**

```
| col0 | col1 | col2  | col3 | col4 |
| ---- | ---- | ----- | ---- | ---- |
| milk | egg  | juice |      |      |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7BK2dXL5SuiHPDhh7tTtvr/0)

Comment: This is a sticking plaster masking deeper design problems.