# Index on unique field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, database-design, indexing, unique-constraint

I have a users table and there is an index on that table:

`add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree`

The index type is btree and `email` is a unique field.
Is it worth having this index or is it better to just remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the column is defined [**`UNIQUE`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS), it is indexed with a unique btree index automatically anyway, because that's how Postgres implements a `UNIQUE` constraint.

An additional index would be redundant, dead freight. Delete it.

Details:

- [How does PostgreSQL enforce the UNIQUE constraint / what type of index does it use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9066972/how-does-postgresql-enforce-the-unique-constraint-what-type-of-index-does-it-u/9067108#9067108)

Answer (score 1):

I would remove it first and then use `lol_dba db:find_indexes` from [lol_dba](https://github.com/plentz/lol_dba)  to see if it recommends adding the index.

Comment: so this gem only tells you if you need to add an index?

Comment: That's it's most important feature