# Does a Postgres UNIQUE constraint imply an index?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, indexing, constraints, unique-constraint

When adding a unique constraint to a Postgres table does that imply that an index has also been added to that table?

Meaning, if I add a `UNIQUE` constraint on a `text` column, does that text column now have an index or does an index have to be added separately?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Yes.**
`UNIQUE` constraints are implemented using a unique B-tree index in Postgres.

See:

- [How does PostgreSQL enforce the UNIQUE constraint / what type of index does it use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9066972/how-does-postgresql-enforce-the-unique-constraint-what-type-of-index-does-it-u/9067108#9067108)