# Does PostgreSQL self join ignore indexes?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, self-join, postgresql-performance

I have the following table in Postgresql 8.4.12:

```
           Table "public.ratings"
 Column |          Type          | Modifiers
--------+------------------------+-----------
 userid | character varying(128) |
 item   | character varying(128) |
 score  | integer                |
Indexes:
    "ratings_item" btree (item)
    "ratings_ui" btree (userid, item)
    "ratings_userid" btree (userid)
```

I would like to perform a self join to find items rated by all users that rated a specific item.  For simplicity sake, I'll use a query to just get the number of ratings for each suspect similar item like so;

```
select r2.item,sum(1)
from ratings r1
left join ratings r2 using (userid)
where r1.item='an3.php'
group by r2.item
```

The query works but for my table with 36 million records, it takes forever. When I explain the statement, I get the following:

```
 GroupAggregate  (cost=8102958.42..8247621.18 rows=16978 width=17)    ->  Sort  (cost=8102958.42..8151108.60 rows=19260072 width=17)
         Sort Key: r2.item
         ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=1458652.29..4192647.43 rows=19260072 width=17)
               Hash Cond: ((r1.userid)::text = (r2.userid)::text)
               ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on ratings r1  (cost=868.20..77197.24 rows=24509 width
=22)
                     Recheck Cond: ((item)::text = 'an3.php'::text)
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ratings_item  (cost=0.00..862.07 rows=24509 width=0)
                           Index Cond: ((item)::text = 'an3.php'::text)
               ->  Hash  (cost=711028.93..711028.93 rows=36763293 width=39)
                     ->  Seq Scan on ratings r2  (cost=0.00..711028.93 rows=36763293 width
=39)
```

From experience, I assume the "Seq Scan on ratings r2" is the culprit.

On another note, if I search for an item that doesn't exist:

```
select r2.item,sum(1) from ratings r1 left join ratings r2 using (userid)
where r1.item='targetitem' group by r2.item;
```

It appears to work fine (ie no results are returned and it is immediate)

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=2235887.19..2248234.70 rows=16978 width=17)    ->  Sort  (cost=2235887.19..2239932.29 rows=1618038 width=17)
         Sort Key: r2.item
         ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.00..1969469.94 rows=1618038 width=17)
               ->  Index Scan using ratings_item on ratings r1  (cost=0.00..8317.74 rows=2 059 width=22)
                     Index Cond: ((item)::text = 'targetitem'::text)
               ->  Index Scan using ratings_userid on ratings r2  (cost=0.00..947.24 rows= 419 width=39)
                     Index Cond: ((r1.userid)::text = (r2.userid)::text)
```

The same table and query works fine in MySQL but I'm not in a position to migrate my recommender system to another database.

Did I do something wrong or is this something with Postgres? Is there a work around?

Comment: How many rows there are matching to the an3.php? Has vacuum analyze been run? If there are very many rows matching, the index may not be of use,

Comment: There could be millions of possible results. Mysql is able to return something in a few seconds for each query. I'll run vacuum analyze ratings and try again.

Comment: vacum analyze ratings completed but it still wants to do a sequential scan on ratings r2.

Comment: Is there a limit as to how many results can be returned by an index in Postgresql?

Answer (score 4):

To answer the (rhetorical) question in the title: No.

I see quite a few problems here, starting in the first line.

[Postgres 8.4 has reached EOL last year](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/). Nobody should be using it any more, it's too old. Upgrade to a current version if at all possible.

Barring that, you should at least be at the latest minor version. 8.4.12 was released 2012-06-04 and is missing two years of bug and security fixes. 8.2.23 is the last release for the dead version.
[Read the versioning policy of the project.](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)

Next, `varchar(128)` is very inefficient as PK / FK, especially for a table with millions of rows. Needlessly big and expensive to process. Use [`integer` or `bigint`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html) instead. Or [`UUID`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-uuid.html) if you really need a bigger number space (I doubt it).

Next, I don't see a `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY` constraint on `(userid, item)` ([which would obsolete an additional index on the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29655439/does-a-postgres-unique-constraint-imply-an-index/29655542#29655542)). Either your table definition is lacking or your query is wrong, or your question is broken.

Try this rewritten query:

```
SELECT r2.item, count(*) AS ct
FROM  (
   SELECT userid
   FROM   ratings
   WHERE  item = 'an3.php'
   GROUP  BY 1  -- should not be necessary, but constraint is missing
   ) r1
JOIN   ratings r2 USING (userid)
GROUP  BY 1;
```

In modern Postgres you would need two indexes for best performance. On `(item, userid)` and `(userid, item)`.

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27493/3684)

In Postgres 9.2+ you might even get index-only scans out of this. I am not sure how to get the best out of your outdated version. Either way, `varchar(128)` is an expensive data type for indexes, too.