# Does a multicolumn constraint create indexes for each column or a unified index?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, unique-constraint

I have a unique constraint over two columns in an association table, e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE PersonImage (
id serial PRIMARY KEY,
person_id integer REFERENCES Person (id),
image_id integer REFERENCES Image (id),
CONSTRAINT person_image_uc UNIQUE (person_id, image_id));
```

Does the constraint make indexes for `person_id` and `image_id` independently or does it create a unified index?

**My aim** is make it faster to search through `person_id` and `image_id` independently by creating indexes, but I don't want to create more overhead if this is automatically done in the constraint.

Comment: Unless there's something completely unique to Postgree, the index is a composite one. Keep in mind that an Index is something that will speed up your searches but will slow down your inserts and updates (when affecting the indexed columns). So, a good practice is to keep an eye on statistics before creating indexes just because.

Comment: One more thing (that I'm geting from what your code is suggesting me): Do you ever search or reference the column "id" somewhere? Cause if it is just there to act as a PK, you could take it off your model and use a composite PK (person_id, image_id) without the need for the constraint (PKs already have indexes and already are unique enforced).

Comment: Thanks, Marcelo. I had to have an independent, id column because it's apparently a Django standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `UNIQUE` constraint is *almost*, but not quite the same as a `UNIQUE` index on the same columns in the same order. But there are several subtle differences.

See:

- [How does PostgreSQL enforce the UNIQUE constraint / what type of index does it use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9066972/how-does-postgresql-enforce-the-unique-constraint-what-type-of-index-does-it-u/9067108#9067108)
- [Does a Postgres UNIQUE constraint imply an index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29655439/does-a-postgres-unique-constraint-imply-an-index/29655542#29655542)

Effectively, you get a single multicolumn unique index on `(person_id, image_id)` with your constraint. Since you *also* want to search on `image_id` independently, add another index on `(image_id)` or `(image_id, person_id)`. Detailed explanation:

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27481/is-a-composite-index-also-good-for-queries-on-the-first-field/27493#27493)

Answer (score 1):

This is functionally equivalent to:

```
create unique index unq_personimage_person_image on personimage(person_id, image_id);
```

The unique index is used to implement the constraint.  Because the constraint in one two columns, both must be in the index.