# Multiple conditions in INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-division

I have two tables `user` and `product` which have a one-to-many relationship (one `user`may have multiple `product`s).

I want to create a query to get all `user`s  which have both an orange and a banana. In my example below this would be `john` and `leeroy`.

**How can I formulate my query to do that?**

With only one condition I would go like:

```
SELECT * FROM "user" 
INNER JOIN "product" ON "product"."fk_user" = "user"."id"
WHERE "product"."product" = 'banana';
```

The `user` table

```
╔════╦═════════╗
║ id ║ name    ║
╠════╬═════════╣
║ 1  ║ michael ║
╠════╬═════════╣
║ 2  ║ john    ║
╠════╬═════════╣
║ 3  ║ leeroy  ║
╠════╬═════════╣
║ 4  ║ tony    ║
╚════╩═════════╝
```

The `product` table

```
╔═════════╦═════════╗
║ product ║ fk_user ║
╠═════════╬═════════╣
║ orange  ║ 1       ║
╠═════════╬═════════╣
║ orange  ║ 2       ║
╠═════════╬═════════╣
║ banana  ║ 2       ║
╠═════════╬═════════╣
║ banana  ║ 3       ║
╠═════════╬═════════╣
║ orange  ║ 3       ║
╠═════════╬═════════╣
║ banana  ║ 4       ║
╚═════════╩═════════╝
```

Comment: One join may not be enough for this.

Comment: You don't need a join. See my answer on this. This isn't a product table by the way; because a record in the table doesn't uniquely represent a product. You should ideally have a product table with one row per product and a user_product table linking product and user.

Comment: Do you just need `user_id` or more columns from the `user` table? Is there a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint to enforce referential integrity? A `UNIQUE` constraint to disallow dupes on `product(product, fk_user)`?  Your version of Postgres?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use two joins:

```
SELECT u.* 
FROM user u
INNER JOIN product p1
ON p1.fk_user=u.id
AND p1.product='banana'
INNER JOIN product p2
ON p2.fk_user=u.id
AND p2.product='orange'
```

Comment: One banana is supposed to be an orange I guess. ;)

Comment: @stickybit derp duh derp derp. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Group by user und use `HAVING` to check the user's products.

```
select *
from user
where id in
(
  select fk_user
  from product
  group by fk_user
  having count(case when product = 'orange' then 1 end) > 0
     and count(case when product = 'banana' then 1 end) > 0
);
```

Edit: I should add that there are several ways to write such subquery. A `WHERE` clause could speed this up, and with such clause you could just count distinct products found:

```
select *
from user
where id in
(
  select fk_user 
  from product 
  where product in ('orange', 'banana') 
  group by fk_user
  having count(distinct product) = 2 -- two different products: orange and banana
);
```

Answer (score 3):

The most straightforward declaration (IMHO) would be to use two `IN` clauses:

```
select *
from user
where id in
(
  select fk_user
  from product
  WHERE product = 'orange')
and id in
(
  select fk_user
  from product
  WHERE product = 'banana')
```

Comment: Canonical may not be the right word - my intent is to say "the most straightforward _declarative_" way. It's the closest SQL that expresses the _intent_ of the query (`EXISTS` is a close second IMHO)

Comment: Fair enough. (`EXISTS` would win that competition from where I stand - and it can be faster while it's never slower.)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the user id and not the name, you can use aggregation:

```
SELECT p.fk_user
FROM product p
WHERE p.product in ('banana', 'orange')
GROUP BY p.fk_user
HAVING COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE p.product = 'banana') > 0 AND
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE p.product = 'orange') > 0;
```

If you need additional columns from `user` as well, I would go with the `IN` version suggested by DStanley, although I would use `EXISTS` rather than `IN`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case of [relational-division](/questions/tagged/relational-division).
**If** (like is the typical case, and your sample data seems to support it) ...

- all you need is the user ID
- there is a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint enforcing referential integrity
- and a `UNIQUE` constraint on `product(product, fk_user)` - (implicitly [providing the perfect index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29655542/939860) for my query)

.. then this is as fast as it gets:

```
SELECT fk_user
FROM   product b
JOIN   product o USING (fk_user)
WHERE  b.product = 'banana'
AND    o.product = 'orange';
```

We collected an arsenal of base techniques here:

- [How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation/7774879#7774879)

The best pick depends on missing specifications - and personal preferences to a degree.

Aside: [`user`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html) is a resserved word, don't use it as table name.