# Why should we avoid CREATE UNIQUE INDEX?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I've heard that we should avoid using

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX indx ON tbl(clmn)
```

because in fact it creates a `UNIQUE` constraint without naming it so in a contraints table. But What is the different? If we use

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ADD CONSTRAINT un_cn UNIQUE(clmn)
```

we create a consraint, but it also creates an index on `clmn` we don't explicitly name.

So why is the second form preffered?

Comment: This one should give you a better explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9066972/how-does-postgresql-enforce-the-unique-constraint-what-type-of-index-does-it-u/9067108#9067108

Comment: Actually I _prefer_ `create unique index` because it is more flexible than a unique constraint

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Indeed, as it's explained in the dupe I think that it's all about personal perference. The implementation of UNIQUE may get changed in future release.