# Use functions in unique constraint on multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, unique-constraint, postgresql-10

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE games (
    red int unique, 
    blue int unique, 
    unique (LEAST(red, blue), GREATEST(red, blue)),
    check (red <> blue)
);
```

When I try to make the table, it errors `syntax error at or near "("`. Are functions like `LEAST` and `GREATEST` not allowed when making 2 columns unique? The purpose of the least and greatest functions is so that when one ID is in red, it can't also be in another record in the blue column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an index on an expression.  I'm not so sure you can put a unique constraint on expressions.  But this does what you want:

```
CREATE TABLE games (
    red int not null, 
    blue int not null, 
    check (red <> blue)
);

create unique index unq_games_red_blue on ( least(red, blue), greatest(red, blue) );
```

Note:  You probably don't want `red` and `blue` to be unique individually.  If there are, there is no reason for a unique constraint on the pair.

Comment: @Punknoodles . . . Unique constraints are implemented through unique indexes.  Functionally it is the same.  There might be some minor differences, such as whether the constraint shows up in the list of constraints on the table.

Comment: thanks for the help. might want to delete the unique constraint line in your code block though...

Answer (score 0):

`UNIQUE` constraints can only be made for one or more columns, not expressions (including functions) like you can use in `UNIQUE` indexes. While the constraint is implemented using an index, there are a few remaining differences. See:

- [How does PostgreSQL enforce the UNIQUE constraint / what type of index does it use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9066972/how-does-postgresql-enforce-the-unique-constraint-what-type-of-index-does-it-u/9067108#9067108)

BTW:

> The purpose of the least and greatest functions is so that when one ID is in red, it can't also be in another record in the blue column.

That's not what the multicolumn `UNIQUE` index achieves. Only the combination is unique, so `(1,3)` would be a dupe of `(3,1)`, but `(2,1)` is still allowed, so `1` can still *be in another record in the `blue` column*. Your description does not match the constraint. At least one of both is off.

Also be aware that `NULL` evades your rules. So you may need `NOT NULL` constraints, too. See:

- [Create unique constraint with null columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289100/create-unique-constraint-with-null-columns/8289253#8289253)