# PostgreSQL OK to use HASH exclude constraint for uniqueness?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, unique-index, ltree, postgresql-10

Since hashes are smaller than lengthy text, it seems to me that they could be preferred to b-trees for ensuring column uniqueness.

For the sole purpose of ensuring uniqueness, is there any reason the following isn't OK in PG 10?

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  path ltree,
  EXCLUDE USING HASH ((path::text) WITH =)
);
```

I assume hash collisions are internally dealt with. Would be useless otherwise.

I will use a `GiST` index for query enhancement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think [quoting the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-EXCLUDE) on this sums it up:

> Although it's allowed, there is little point in using B-tree or hash
>   indexes with an exclusion constraint, because this does nothing that
>   an ordinary unique constraint doesn't do better. So in practice the access method will always be GiST or SP-GiST.

All the more since you want to create a GiST index anyway. The exclusion constraint with `USING GIST` will create a matching GiST index as implementation detail automatically. No point in maintaining another, inefficient hash index not even being used in queries.

For simple uniqueness (`WITH =`) a plain `UNIQUE` btree index is more efficient. If your keys are very long, consider a **unique index** on a hash [***expression***](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-expressional.html) (using any immutable function) to reduce size. Like:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX test_path_hash_uni_idx ON test (my_hash_func(path));
```

Related:

- [How does PostgreSQL enforce the UNIQUE constraint / what type of index does it use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9066972/how-does-postgresql-enforce-the-unique-constraint-what-type-of-index-does-it-u/9067108#9067108)

`md5()` would be a simple option as hash function.

- [Convert hex in text representation to decimal number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8316164/convert-hex-in-text-representation-to-decimal-number/8335376#8335376)
- [Would index lookup be noticeably faster with char vs varchar when all values are 36 chars](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89429/would-index-lookup-be-noticeably-faster-with-char-vs-varchar-when-all-values-are/89433#89433)

Before **Postgres 10** the use of hash indexes was discouraged. But [with the latest updates](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/release-10.html#idm46428657937024), this has improved. Robert Haas (core developer) sums it up in a blog entry:

- [PostgreSQL's Hash Indexes Are Now Cool](http://rhaas.blogspot.co.at/2017/09/postgresqls-hash-indexes-are-now-cool.html)

```
CREATE INDEX test_path_hash_idx ON test USING HASH (path);
```

Alas (missed that in my draft), the access method "hash" does not support unique indexes, yet. So I would still go with the unique index on a hash expression above. (But no hash function that reduces information can fully guarantee uniqueness of the key - which may or may not be an issue.)

Comment: One note: hash indexes do not support `UNIQUE`, so I'll need to use a C hash function and non-unique b-tree index with a `BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER` that detects hash AND field equality.

Comment: @IamIC: Thanks for pointing out. My last addition was too optimistic. But anyway, the unique (btree) expression index using your hash function would seem simpler / faster / more reliable.

Comment: Hash function + trigger seems very worthwhile to me, especially when the source is of considerable length. Please note that the index cannot be unique in this case as there may be collisions, even with MD5.

Comment: I agree that MD5 would be simpler in that it wouldn't require a custom C function. However, xxHash (for example) is considerably faster (which may or may not be meaningless) and is either 32 or 64-bit (which may be advantageous space and performance-wise over MD5).

Comment: @IamIC: `md5()` is just a simple (good) example. It's not perfect, the cryptographic component adds some cost that may not be needed ... Your hash function may very well be superior. The cost is not *too* important, since it's not re-executed in select queries, the index is based on the *result*.

Comment: I agree. Pragmatically, MD5 wins.

Comment: With `md5()` (or other functions producing compatible results), consider casting to `uuid` like [demonstrated in the linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8335376/939860).

Comment: I agree. Much more space efficient. I learned that from you a while ago :)

Comment: Thanks much, Erwin! Merry Christmas to you, too! :)

Comment: The `EXCLUDE USING HASH` solution seems to have some advantages: 1. UNIQUE btree index on a fast and small hash function will cause false errors on collisions. 2. Practically collision-free hash functions might (?) cause noticeable slowdown 3. `EXCLUDE` creates a simple hash index, which can also be used directly by queries. In contrast, the btree index on the hash function will only be used by queries which explicitly do something like `where md5(ltree1) = md5(ltree2) and ltree1 = ltree2`. Edit: My comment was about the case where the values are too large for a plain UNIQUE btree.

Comment: @FunctorSalad: The OP wrote: `I assume hash collisions are internally dealt with.` *Are they?* If so, It'd appear you have a point for values too large for btree indexes. But then why does hash not support `UNIQUE` indexes?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: Assuming hash indexes use the `hash$type` family of functions (not sure), [it does seem do deal with collisions internally](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hxQZjZmCSKdQiBQJuKoq2S/2). I would also expect this behavior because we were semantically asking Postgres for exclusion on the `=` operator, not on the hashes.

Comment: You really seem to have a point. Still confusing that (a) hash indexes do not support `UNIQUE`, and (b) the manual states that `... this does nothing that an ordinary unique constraint doesn't do better.` (You might want to start a separate question for this.) I posted the case to pgsql-general: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAGHENJ6NT9OaAyOKykuZrss8k0rqM8%2BDsL18WBJuynAgXyk3Cw%40mail.gmail.com