# SQLAlchemy: how to filter on PgArray column types?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

In pure postgres we can write:

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE 10000 = ANY (array_field);
```

or

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE 10000 = ALL (array_field);
```

How to do the same with the help of sqlalchemy without raw sql?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`a = ANY(b_array)` is equivalent to `a`**`IN`**`(elements_of_b_array)`<sup>1</sup>.

Therefore you can use the [`in_()` method](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/expression_api.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.in_).

I can't remember ever having used `a = ALL(b_array)` in all my years with PostgreSQL. Have you?

---

If you are dealing with an **array column** and want to test whether it contains a given element (or all elements of a given array) in that column, then you can utilize [PostgreSQL array operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-OPERATORS-TABLE) `@>` (`contains`)  or more appropriately the inverse sibling **`<@`** (`is contained by`).

Array operators carry the advantage that they can be supported with a **GIN index** on the array column (unlike the `ANY` construct).

Your SQL statement:

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE 10000 = ANY (array_field);
```

is (almost)<sup>1</sup> equivalent to

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE 10000 <@ array_field;
```

I am no expert with SQLAlchemy, but according to the [tutorial in the SQLAlchemy manual](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html), you can use any operator:

> If you have come across an operator which really isn’t available, you
>   can always use the **`op()`** method; this generates whatever
>   operator you need:
>
> ```py
> >>> print users.c.name.op('tiddlywinks')('foo') users.name tiddlywinks :name_1
> ```

Bold emphasis mine. Your statement could look like this in SQLA:

```py
s = select([my_table], array_field.op('@>')('ARRAY[10000]'))
```

Or with alternative input syntax for PostgreSQL array values:

```py
s = select([my_table], array_field.op('@>') (cast('{10000}', int[])))
```

---

<sup>1</sup> There is a subtle difference with NULL handling:

```sql
SELECT '{NULL}'::int[] <@ ... -- that's an array with a single NULL element
```

always yields `FALSE`.

```sql
SELECT NULL IN (...)
SELECT NULL = ANY (...)
SELECT NULL::int[] <@ ...
```

always yield `NULL`.

If you are not going to query for `NULL` values, you can ignore this.

Comment: Ok, how to write such query: `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE 5 = ANY(array_field)` ? as I understand `in_()` won't help in this case... `Session.query(MyTable).filter(MyTable.array_field.in_(?????)).all()`

Comment: @VitaliPonomar: Sorry, removed the misleading info. I looked into this some more and think I found a proper solution. Consider amended answer.

Comment: I have one problem. How would I write `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE [10000,200,600] = ANY (array_field);` - The meaning is select the row if either of the value from `[10000,200,600]` is present in the column `array_field` ?

Comment: If you want to use the `ALL` array comparator, import it from the Postgres dialect (`from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import All`) and pass it as the argument to the `having()` method on the `Query` object:

`query.having(All(1, func.array_agg(Widget.id)))`

[Full docs are here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_1/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.All)