# How to efficiently index PostgreSQL array columns for "ALL" operator?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

My questions is based on this question: [SQLAlchemy: how to filter on PgArray column types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10344468/sqlalchemy-how-to-filter-on-pgarray-column-types/10344851)

But I really need to use the "ALL" operator. In my case, I have an array of dates. And I need to find all rows in which each element from the date array is greater than or equal to a given date. E.g.: '2021-06-20' <= ALL(dates_arr)

Which type of index should I choose for my case?

Comment: I'm not a postgre expert, but can you find the least date first and compare to it? Something like `'2021-06-20' <= MIN(dates_arr)`?

Comment: @PavelSmirnov Hmm, that's a good suggestion, I'll check it

Comment: Why do you really need to use ALL?

Comment: @PavelSmirnov thanks a lot, your suggestion works. Spasibo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being less than each member of an array is the same as being less than the least member.

In PostgreSQL, "min" is for aggregating over rows, "least" is for 'aggregating' its list of arguments.  But I don't think there is anything built in for determining the least member of an array.  You can always define your own function to do it.

```
create or replace function least_arr(anyarray) returns anyelement immutable parallel safe language sql as 
    $$ select min(x) from unnest($1) f(x) $$;

create index ON foo (least_arr(dates_arr));

explain analyze select * from foo where '2021-06-15'::date < least_arr(dates_arr);
```